# Lots of users don't accept any answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

There are a lot of posts on Meta revolving around how to point a newbie to accept their own answer.

However, the main problem is, that many users don't care to accept an answer at all. If, for instance, they only intend to ask one question here and then leave forever, then they have no intention in accepting or upvoting anything, or even caring if users downvote their own question.

**There is no hint** pointing out that you should accept an answer! Even if you're willing to accept one and forget about it, then you don't get reminded.

---

I think there should be a third button in the menu bar:

[image: menu bar]

Something that indicates unaccepted answers, and of course the option to mark it as unaccepted. This is because sometimes there is no acceptable answer.

This still doesn't solve the issue of users that only drop by here and post no more than one question at all. But there are also users that post questions on a regular basis and don't care for the community thus not accepting or upvoting. If you hint them with a number indicator (see screenshot), then they might accept an answer (or mark is as "unaccepted") just to get rid of the "annoying" popup.

**What do you think?**

Comment: If you view your question list, there is a hint to accept an answer if your question has them with up-votes.

Comment: Accepting an answer is *not required*. You can educate new users that never accepted an answer and have not been around all that long, gently, by pointing to the feature being available. But we removed the 'accept percentage' indicator we had in the past for a reason.

Comment: And the system definitely points out that accepting an answer is available, with just-in-time help.

Comment: I noticed that, but for what reason is there no indicator?

Comment: Looking at SO as a knowledge repository, it does not make a difference if an answer is accepted or not - or rather, accepting an answer can even make it worse if the selected answer is bad, see e.g. all the discussions about accepted PHP answers with mysql injections. The only downside to a good answer not being accepted is that the answerer loses 15 rep, which is IMO not a valid reason to nag people about accepting.

Comment: Probably the biggest hangup is that a questioner cannot accept an answer until two hours later.  Important.  But lots of them just don't want to invest that amount of time.  Or are attached to their user account and just create a new one if they ever come back.  Pretty unfixable right now.  If this bothers you then just pay attention to the question and the user's profile, you can always tell.

Comment: *Or*... just shrug your shoulders, look to Polaris, and smile that all these points don't really matter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Users are under no obligation to accept answers.

It's often more useful for future visitors to check the answer(s) with the most upvotes rather than the answer that's been accepted as they might have got to the *real* problem.

Comment: The usual case is answering a newbie's question, being the only one to answer with no upvotes and no accepts. This results in newbies don't getting help at all. Afterall, it's all about reputation.

Comment: Right, not about sharing knowledge.

Comment: It's about sharing knowledge, of course. But you have to offer some kind of incentive, in this case reputation. That's why bulletin boards are chaotic and not constructive compared to Q&A sites, generally speaking.

Comment: @bytecode77 "This results in newbies don't getting help at all" - I wish. In what fantasy world are you living, and can I visit? The exact opposite is the case in the popular tags such as java, python, php etc - people rush to get the low-hanging fruits and often any noob question gets 5 similar (and upvoted) answers in 2 minutes...

Comment: Right, not because people upvote good content, downvote bad content, close off-topic and unclear questions, and not because of us moderators.

Comment: What a **load of horse-hockey**.  *Of course* they are under no "obligation" to accept an answer, or do anything whatsoever. You might as well say "they're under no obligation to X" for any process where we do give users hints and strong modal alertx that they should do "X".  No mystery.