# Replace the concept of accepted answers with that of solved questions

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Quoting from a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326341/39648)...

> The site was explicitly, and very vocally, created specifically with the point of benefiting future readers, and explicitly not there just to benefit the one person asking.

I want to say that people do not care if the problem was solved for the OP or not. They are looking for a solution to the specific problem they have. OP's accepted solution may not be the reader's accepted solution. And as such it does not make sense to have an accepted answer.

IMO it is better to let the users vote and decide if the question has been answered to their satisfaction. The question should be marked as solved if the number of upvotes for the solved criteria exceeds the number of downvotes. Thus making the solved/unsolved situation more dynamic. This will also help in flagging stale information. When the answers are no longer relevant people can simply down-vote and mark the question as unsolved.

Also (quoting from an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326119/39648))...

> FWIW, I've suggested a variety of things, internally, to "unpin" accepted answers from the top spot, including limiting it to those that were negatively scored (<= -3) to minimize the scope of the answers impacted. My suggestions were overruled because the pinning of accepted answers is part of what makes our sites different from others - it's the indication that an answer worked for the OP - we don't want to lose the signal for those answers or hide them way down on a list of a ton of answers. Unfortunately, at this time this is not something that is going to be implemented.

To solve this problem I think it's better to replace the concept of accepted answers with that of solved questions.

Comment: So from the mass of answers I would no longer know which one the OP tried and found successful. This simply seems to remove useful information.

Comment: I see greater merit in judging answers by their vote count instead of what a single person found useful.

Comment: People should stop downvoting questions just because they disagree with what's being proposed. They should instead judge the question on whether it's valid and well-written, and then leave a comment.

Answer (score 9):

Do we really care if an question is "Solved" or if it has an "Accepted Answer"?
**No.**
We care about neither of these.

The concept of an Accepted answer isn't core to stack exchange anyway.
Particularly if [Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/) comes to pass.
But even if it doesn't.

When you google a question and end up at Stack Overflow, you don't really get anything much out of the Accepted Answer, you look at what the answers are. 
You only care about "There are answers" or "There are not answers".

You could say that is what "Solved" is going to tell you.
But this information is already clear -- there are answers or there are not.

Thus this is a meaningless change of terminology.

Questions are already move off the [*Unanswered Questions*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) tab once they have 1 or more answers with more upvotes than downvotes (min 1).
So the only Mechanical part of changing "Accepted Answer" to "Solved" is already implemented.

Comment: "You could say that is what 'Solved' is going to tell you. But this information is already clear -- there are answers or there are not." This is not correct. Presence of answers does not guarantee that a problem has been solved. There are many questions on stackoverflow with dud answers and positive scores. It would be good to have a visual indication of the quality of answers. You could argue the solved/unsolved indicator could be computed from the votes accrued by the answers present on the page but that is besides the point. An indicator will be helpful regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Note that whether a question is "solved" can change from false to true, then back to false, as technology changes.

I've seen many questions that were problems that I was actually facing, even though the question had been posted years earlier.

In many of these cases, the highest voted answers and/or the accepted answer were no longer valid.  However, answers posted years later, which were not nearly as highly upvoted (due to less visibility) contained solutions that were much more appropriate for my current situation.

So trying to add more meaning to the status of a question as "solved" instead of simply having an accepted answer could simply be misleading.

Your suggestion to address this by having people downvote the answers that are no longer valid seems impractical; many of these answers were quite good at the time they were written, and have potentially dozens or even hundreds of upvotes.  The chances of people coming back to later downvote them for being correct, but only correct for older versions of technology, is unlikely, impractical (since people who previously upvoted would need the answer to be edited before they could reverse their vote), and an unfair penalty for people who contributed meaningful content (subsequent loss of reputation as a reward for putting in a good answer).

Comment: "Your suggestion to address this by having people downvote the answers that are no longer valid" 
This is not what I suggested. I want the question to have a additional pair of vote buttons for the question. This does not have to be an a per answer basis.

Comment: @SandeepDatta  that was not clear in the Question, that you were suggesting a new set of voting buttons. I interpreted it, and I think most other people interpreted it as using the existing voting buttons. I think it may be a bit late to edit this question. So you might want to just ask another one, I guess (I don't think it would find favour, but downvotes on meta don't count, so you can float the idea if you want)

Answer (score 2):

It's a rare thing that the problem I'm researching is *exactly* the same problem that someone else has encountered and solved before. Very nearly identical? --Possibly. Fairly close? --More likely. Distantly related? --Most likely. Outside the ballpark but still in the same city? --Usually.

When I'm searching for answers, I'm looking for "ways of thinking" far more than searching for an exact solution. (Caveat: sometimes I am looking for the specific syntax or sequence of statements to implement a desired outcome.) Because it's the "ways of thinking" that will improve my code not only for "this" problem, but future problems I encounter that I know understand how to solve.

So what I'm looking for is not solutions (exactly), but can I understand the thinking that is going on for a problem similar to my own that I can apply. If I make a wild guess, I'd say SO has solved close to 75% of the problems I've searched for by reading threads that are only fairly close or distantly related to my problem. Tagging a thread as [Solved] wouldn't make me read that one first because chances are it won't solve MY problem.

I do understand many people are looking for solutions to their exact problem and get frustrated when they can't find that exact answer. I have long appreciated the SO community for the depth of information here and the "ways of thinking" that have improved my own ability to solve problems. What I hope is that folks who keep returning to SO to search for answers will gradually learn how to pull bits and pieces of answers from many sources and raise their own skills to synthesize their own solution.

Comment: Then you wouldn't mind if the "accepted answer" check mark is replaced with a Solved indicator (because given your line of thought you shouldn't care for accepted answers either)?

Comment: If the "accepted answer" check mark were replaced by a Solved indicator, it would mean exactly the same to me. But I'm just one guy -- who can say if my ways of searching are the same as other folks. At the risk of forcing the discussion into a semantic debate between "Accepted" and "Solved", viewing a question as "solved" would mean (to me) that the question was clearly asked and an clear answer provided that perfectly describes the solution. I'm not sure how often that happens on SO. My guess is that many answers and comments help the OP solve the problem, but the true solution isn't given.

Comment: ... the true solution isn't given directly but the discussion is what helped the OP solve the problem. So an "Accepted" check mark given as a nod to the person who responded seems more appropriate than marking the question as "Solved". Again, I'm not trying to nitpick. That's just what the words mean to me.