# Is there a way that very low quality answers do not stay on top of decent answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, accepted-answer

Recently, I have stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010987/2780791) which is in a very weird situation: it is accepted and its vote score is -20.

This is very low for an answer on the actual SO site (as opposed to meta where big minus is not so rarely met). Clearly, it is not helpful for a very long time.

**Question:** Is there a way to get rid of these answers or at least do not display them above more useful ones?

Comment: Knowledgable Android people with 20k reputation can vote to delete it (if they stumble upon it and decide they want to do it).

Comment: Related (but status-declined): [Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/812149).

Comment: there should be some sort of badge for [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/636339) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing can be done, if you are using sorting by votes, It will stay on top because it has acceptance vote which outweigh even top voted answer in term of sorting. what you can do is to use sort by active/oldest at best.

Comment: Curiously, for **some** questions, it does seem to be unpinned. In [this extreme example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp), when sorting by votes the accepted answer is shown at the bottom, despite being accepted. Weird?

Comment: @yivi mmmhh you are right, I am not sure if they've applied any threshold for sorting in this case.

Comment: @yivi The answer in your example was a self-answer from the OP. In that situation, other rules apply.

Comment: So, the plot thickens... ;) Yup, was a self answer, got it from the sede query above. Thanks @MrLister