# Order Stack Overflow answers by votes, including the accepted answer

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to move the most voted answer to the top of the answers and make the marked one be sorted as well?

[image: Example]

Comment: Questions about using [so] or any Stack Exchange site should go on the per-site meta or [metase].

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only using a userscript. You can find one [on SoftwareRecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18392/19860) where this same question was asked.

See also the [meta discussion for unpinning the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/2065702).