# Where do Developers Learn, Share & ​Build Their Career?

Tags: discussion, scope, stack-exchange, homepage, seo

Recently, the title of the main front page has changed to include the phrase,

> Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers

Does this change to the page title serve any purpose that goes beyond SEO?

Comment: Are you asking...in general, or as it applies to some service that Stack Overflow provides?

Comment: The title of the (main) stack overflow page seems to have changed today, from "Stack Overflow" to "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share & ​Build Their Careers - Stack Overflow" (which is a bit redundant). It's not a big deal, but ... maybe *that's* the reason of why I wonder why it was done...

Comment: Oh...that's some interesting branding.  I can see it if I'm in an incognito tab, but otherwise I see no new title.  Wonder how many people *actually* see it/pay attention to it.

Comment: @Makoto *"I see no new title"* - A wild guess: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ ?

Comment: @Makoto: I'm logged in, and I see it.

Comment: I can blame caching but at the same time, I've worked around it.  I seldom notice website titles anyhow as my open number of tabs regularly exceeds 10 on any given day.

Comment: `Where Future Pointy Haired Bosses poorly Copy, Paste, and Plagiarize other Developers Careers` - on their way to Management.

Comment: I thought it is a question and want to learn but instead, it is a misunderstanding.

Comment: @cottontail When this question was asked, the quoted title was the actual title. If they now changed it to `Stack Overflow - Where Future Pointy Haired Bosses....` , this question would no longer make sense (but should not be edited accordingly). 

However, 1. your edit reflects the current title, and 2. the change is insignificant - so the edit is fine. (In fact, the change of the title is **SO** insignificant that I'd be curious how much bike-shedding they are capable of, but ... on the other hand, I don't really care (any more)).

Answer (score -13, accepted):

I'm the product manager on the new Developer Affinity and Growth team. SEO is certainly one reason for the change, but we also want to be consistent in the way we describe the vision for Stack Overflow. The new title and description achieve that. Q&A is the way we are currently known to the world, but we are growing in the ways we serve developers. You'll continue to hear more from us regarding our desire to help developers learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. An important part of that will be improving Q&A in addition to new offerings.

Comment: What is "Developer Affinity"?

Comment: But.... I'm not particularly interested in building my career. I am interested in learning *specific* answers to specific questions, and sharing *specific* answers to specific questions, but "learn" in general conjures up the idea of a school (which SO definitely is not) and "share" invokes the idea of a social network (which SO very much is the antithesis of). The new title is annoying to me, and all the more so because it is so prominent.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Developer Affinity = Developer engagement and love. Our team's charter is to continue building on the love that developers have for SO. Our team is still new and in the early stages, but it is safe to assume our plans will include improvements in the Q&A experience that provide compelling value for signing up and staying signed in.

Comment: @DanielPryden Sorry that the new title annoys you. Our thinking is Learn, Share and Build are all descriptive of the activities that current SO users do every day using Q&A and Jobs. Some users may have different connotations. The good news is that the DAG team will be investing time and effort in improving the Q&A experience that I hope you do value.

Comment: "*[B]uilding on the love that developers have for SO*", "*provide compelling value for signing up and staying signed in*". Do those mean that what the community actually wants will start to matter? Setting aside major features (Documentation, Developer Story, etc.), even simple things with consistent consensus such as [unpinning accepted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) keep getting rejected. All the talk about the importance of community seems to be only in words. Is, for instance, moderation part of the engagement vision?

Comment: There's an unstated assumption in this approach that, frankly, worries me. The assumption is that "engagement" is a metric that is worth improving for its own sake. It's not, and should never be. "Engagement", to the degree that it's meaningful at all, is a *proxy* for things you actually care about. Let's face it: the users care about receiving value from the site (mainly in the form of knowledge), and SO (the company) cares about extracting value from the users (mainly via ads). You want more "engagement" because it makes you money. Don't sugarcoat it and pretend this is about anything else.

Comment: A nice, warm welcome to the site... garnished with freezing cold shower of downvotes :-D (You probably know how things work on meta, though). While this answers the question to some extent, changing the `<title>` still seems like an oddly low-level detail (with undesirable consequences) to achieve the goal. (The goal itself is still rather abstract in the way that it is presented here, but ... this alone wouldn't justify the somewhat blunt comments, IMHO). Or to put it that way: I wonder whether the *title* affects the affinity in any way. But maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Yep feeling toasty for sure. In past jobs I've had financial services folks (GS, MS, CS, UBS and such, all just post 2008 crash)and lawyers as customers, so I'm use to the heat. And, of course, I've worked with a lot of developers who created those great products. So this is all par for the course.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). _The community's vision_ is right there in the first sentence of the tour. The experimental "careers" project is of peripheral interest to the community. Especially since it is little more than an irrelevant spam advert generator at this point.

Comment: @Lundin - so Stack Overflow should just be Q&A for all time? We shouldn't try to do something more with our reach?

Comment: @Oded SO should start by improving the core functionality of the site, most notably aiming to improve post quality. For example by phasing out the cumbersome review queues and over time replace them with automatic means to detect and remove poor questions. The moderator tools are crude and could be improved considerably. The on-site search feature is poor - site navigation in general could be improved. There is a need for a working FAQ system. And so on. These things should be priority, not peripheral features or the numerous "pretty buttons" projects.

Comment: @Lundin - priorities. We would love to do all of that. But - if we do and SO runs out of money in the mean time, would you rather we close shop?

Comment: @Oded My point here is, don't pretend that all these peripheral projects were initiated by the community. In fact the community raised many valid concerns about projects such as "Documentation" and "Teams" but SO went through with them anyway. Less failed projects = more money. It would otherwise seem to me that the way to profit would be to get a very good core functionality on SO, then port that to all other sites in the SE network and expand by opening new such sites. Their success will ultimately depend on the quality of the content.

Comment: I don't think anyone pretends that, @Lundin. The success of SO and other sites doesn't automatically translate to a sustainable business. We try new things to see what works - and we are OK with failing, that's how we learn (as people and as organisations). We already have very good core functionality on SO - sure, there's always things to improve and we are working on those too, but working on those exclusively would mean we close doors. I doubt you want that to happen.

Comment: @Oded I concur with that part of Lundin's comment. I'm not a long-time user of the site, but the newer failed-ish sparkly features always seem to go like this: "- Community, we made THIS for you! - Eh, whatever. - Try it, you'll love it! - Wow, this is bad. Please take it away. Or at least change <thing> so that it works. How about changing <years-long list of stuff we actually want>? - Hey, this is for you, it's great how great it is for you! - No, just...no. - We can't put our finger on it, but for some reason we need to unship/rehash/keep aggressively advertising until it starts to work."

Comment: So despite the downvotes and comments, this is as close to an answer as it gets. I've seen that a similar wording is used on the main site when visiting as an unregistered user, so I assume that this is some sort of "branding"/"slogan", last but not least (or even mainly) to convey that SO is more than QA.

Comment: It's far too wordy. learn | share | build might be cool, but also you don't really need to add more branding to SO. Like all good services it grew without cookie-cutter "engagement" dronery. Improve the tools, the content and perhaps the flow for new signups. That'll go much further than fluffy stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Just guessing here but I would say it is because Stack Overflow is so much more than just Q&A these days (docs and jobs). So the title fits the description and the purpose of the site.

Comment: Of course, what you said is true, but changing the title of an established site seems like a big step, and may have have odd consequences (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351544/3182664 ). I wonder whether there is anything (from a technical point of view) that they wanted to achieve with that. The original title was just the site name, and not *"Stack overflow - The Q/A site for programmers - Stack overflow"* either...

Comment: Bingo! Alex, That is exactly why we updated the title. Q&A is one thing we do and thanks to you all we do it well. But there is so much more we are trying and want to do for developers. The new title tries to capture that.

Comment: The new title is classic Eats, Shoots and Leaves. Is SO a site for Learning, and also for Sharing and Building One's Career? Seems like it should be a site where developers learn, share, and build their career. Even better would be a site where developers learn to code, share their knowledge, and build their career, but that would be even longer.

Comment: It would _totally_ suck if SO was wrongfully categorized as "the largest and most reliable Q&A site for programmers". I'm somewhat surprised that Documentation is not in the title :P