# New SO <meta> tags are too long for Google

Tags: discussion, seo

**tl;dr:** Google search results for SO are not displaying correctly due to the length of the new `<meta>` tags.

---

I read [Marco13's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351540/where-do-developers-learn-share-build-their-career) and it seems there's been a recent change to SO's [meta tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta).

I will focus on the [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) and [description](https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description) `<meta>` tags.

### 1- The title tag:

```
<title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share &amp; ​Build Their Careers - Stack Overflow</title>
```

**Actual character count: 90**

**What it is supposed to look like:**

[image]

**What Google actually displays:**

[image]

**Conclusion:**

SO's new title tag is too long. Google trims the title to **61 characters**

**Title tag recommendations from [Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)**:

> If your title is too long, search engines may cut it off—adding an ellipsis ("...")—and could end up not displaying important words. While we generally recommend keeping your titles under 60 characters long, the exact limit is a bit more complicated and is based on a 600-pixel container.

---

### 2- The description tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="Stack Overflow is the largest online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their ​knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million programmers visit us every month."/>
```

**Actual character count: 177**

**What it is supposed to look like:**

[image]

**What Google actually displays:**

[image]

**Conclusion:**

SO's new description tag is also too long. Google trims the description to **155 characters**

**Description tag recommendations from [Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description):**

> Meta descriptions can be any length, but search engines generally truncate snippets longer than 160 characters. It is best to keep meta descriptions long enough that they're sufficiently descriptive, but shorter than that 160-character limit.

Comment: Why are there two Stack Overflows in the title, anyway?

Comment: Why are we linking to W3Schools, anyway?

Comment: Maybe it's intentional, to draw you innnnnnnnnnnnnnn

Comment: These rectangles are hurting my eyes. Please, make them freehand circles! :-(  But seriously, we can be glad that the ellipsis are added there, and that the statement was not distorted ... to *"Where developers build their **car...**"* or something like that...

Comment: It seems a bit repetitive to have "for developers to learn, share​ ​their ​knowledge, and build their careers" in both the title and meta description. Are there any places where the *description* will be displayed without the *title*?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Maybe I'm missing something, but I linked to a high-authority page that defines the `<title>` tag. Please feel free to edit the question and replace the link if you know of a better alternative.

Comment: They need to write those tags like they suggest tag wiki excerpts should be, i.e. drop "Stack Overflow is"

Comment: @Marco13 That would be for [Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Also, it is a stupid market fluff description... How exactly do you "learn a career"? Shouldn't it say trade/profession? Although I hope people don't learn their whole professions on SO... Can we just drop the whole career nonsense? There was a time when SO was a site about programming, for programmers.

Comment: @Lundin The title is missing an oxford comma, which is more obvious if you read the description. Developers aren't "learning a career". They are learning. They are sharing (knowledge). And finally, they are building a career.

Comment: @Ihazkode some people think that W3schools is unreliable, and that MDN is more reliable.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I see. I did not know that but now I do! Andrew Morton has already edited the question and changed the link to an MDN page instead.  Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: I was told back in 2003 to stick with maximum 50 characters for titles, 150 characters for descriptions, and 65 characters per line in body text. Has any of that ever changed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for reporting!

We are shortening both the meta description and the title tag (the meta description is already done!, the title tag will be out there in the next build).

Google does take the full description/title into account even if it doesn't display the whole thing, but we agree that the UX is bad.