# Meet Team DAG! (Developer Affinity & Growth)

Tags: discussion

Not quite dang. Not *quite* unless you see them at play in their native habitats which few will ever travel far enough to do.

Sometimes, you really should pay attention to the folks moving around behind the curtains. We'd like to take a moment to introduce you to a very special product team at Stack Overflow, the one that helps us continue to ensure that all users find *and* have a great experience along with taking on the responsibility of [being that special kind of PM that our Q&A product really needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343387/are-any-major-improvements-planned-for-the-core-qa-engine-is-there-any-point-i/343486#343486).

But if that wasn't exciting, we suppose we can offer a condensed version:

> `tl;dr;`
>
> TeamDAG stands for Developer Affinity & Growth. Their primary purpose is to help folks quickly find value in becoming long-term contributors to all parts of Stack Overflow, including Q&A. They're also in charge of making sure Q&A doesn't ever break, and continues to get what it needs over time as a mature product.
>
> We'll touch on some stuff that this team is currently doing aside from their constant [testing of all of the things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297886/were-formalizing-how-we-announce-tests-a-bit) at the end of this post.

#### What, specifically is this team doing every day?

Have we talked about how big Stack Overflow has gotten lately? It's worth mentioning sometimes that at our scale, some things can be incredibly difficult to measure. Of the five big questions that begin with "W", *why* becomes pretty interesting to us when we try to figure out why people do, or more specifically *don't* do, certain things.

Why don't more folks that keep hitting the site from search engines eventually sign up and take on small units of work to help? Why is anonymous feedback so confusing to interpret? What parts of the system make perfect sense to us because we're so used to them, but throw new folks for a total loop?

Team DAG helps us figure this stuff out and optimize it so that the site gets out of its own way of making sure that there are plenty of new folks to fill the holes that veteran users leave when they really slow down in participation. That's super important, and there's work to be done all over the place.

#### What are they doing for Q&A?

Quite a few of this team's efforts touch Q&A since it is our largest and most mature product, which also makes it chocked full of interesting why-riddles to solve. As DAG touches Q&A quite a bit, it immediately becomes their responsibility *to [avoid breaking it](https://soundcloud.com/irritating-rainbow/theres-a-hammer-remix) at all costs*.

It's also the DAG team's job to make sure that Q&A gets what it needs, approximately when it needs it, and as it stands against *all* of the goals that the team is trying to meet.

They also ensure that [community requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l/291032#291032) get scheduled, discussed and many times ultimately [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or at least [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) if we love an idea but just can't act on it right now.

In short, they're going to help to put the responsiveness back into the mix of the meta and mayhem that can be a big part of actively participating in features and bugs.

#### Do you have an example of what Q&A "needs"?

I certainly do. The [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page has not been touched in years and is in desperate need of an overhaul, and we've already gotten underway with some tests and user surveys from folks that asked questions faring both well and poorly.

There will be another post coming out at some point early next week about that project, what we've learned so far, what we're contemplating and we really hope to get more feedback before we go knee deep in a concept.

The idea: If we do a better job communicating what we want in a question to new users through a better user experience with some extra help initially, they'll have a better experience by asking better questions.

#### Great, but how does knowing all of this help me?

If you see someone mention that they're from the DAG team, you know you'll have a better idea of what their function is within the company, and know that they're here to help especially where user-facing features and testing are concerned.

This should help at least some of you realize more opportunities to jump into discussions, reply to a comment, file an additional bug based on a suggestion, etc.

We're working on being more open and transparent about the moving parts we have working on things, what they're working on, and generally why that's their focus.

#### Any questions for the team, comments or thoughts in general?

Comment or (preferably) answer below! We're really excited about this team coming together to finally put some serious effort into unraveling some tangled messes that took years to perfect, and *finally* having a team and PM now officially in charge of Q&A as a product.

Comment: I have one question... *who* is on Team DAG? Or was "meeting" them just a turn of phrase? But I'm super super excited that Q&A as a product has a dedicated team now!

Comment: @TylerH Some old and new faces depending on what they're working on, but they'll let you know that they're working with DAG as they respond here on meta (I avoided a roll call since it probably won't be static). I'm the bridge between them and the community part of the company, so I'm always singable as someone on / with that team if that helps :)

Comment: Gotcha. So, due to how projects kind of ebb and flow, it's probably a good idea *not* to expect a dedicated section on the Stack Overflow team page? :-)

Comment: @TylerH At this point yes, that's correct. But don't worry, you'll see the DAGwood from the trees soon enough :P

Comment: I'm on the team, @TylerH

Comment: Long live team [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

Comment: I'm the new product manager for Team DAG. Excited to be on the team and work with the community on improvements to Q&A.

Comment: @TimPost Thank you for going where I dared not https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37981947#37981947 On another note... maybe [meta-tag:featured] this post?

Comment: @TylerH I expected it sooner!!! Agree on featuring for a short time (I'll drop it off tomorrow so as not to get in the way of other stuff that might need it).

Comment: Also on the team here @TylerH

Comment: No Antipodeans on the team to vet the acronym? Hope you are going for the [second noun definition and not the first](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define+dag) ; )

Comment: would be interesting to know how did you pick folks for the team? Were there some criteria, or some selection process or something else

Comment: Maybe I'm oldschool. If I want something to know, I'll ask a question. Why do I need a "team" like that on your side? I mean, do you need something like that anyway?

Comment: @Victoria Yes, it takes a team to manage the tests, iterations, gathering feedback, discussions, brainstorming, all of it is work made much lighter with more hands .. just not _too_ many hands.

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but I simply don't believe you this time.  You can make a big deal about yourselves once you've actually done something.

Comment: Thank you for this post, I posted it on my facebook for my Aussie friends. It's hilarious!

Comment: Well, this is a good sign, I suppose. Stack Overflow has finally decided to do something about not passing the Joel Test. It is off to a fairly inauspicious start (the "improve the Ask page" has been sitting silent for over a year now), but any news is good news, I guess. You've really been trying the patience of your veteran users. Why don't you just call them "Team Q&A"?

Comment: @CodyGray [because](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351540/where-do-developers-learn-share-build-their-career/351614?noredirect=1#comment487599_351614) [vision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351626/5067311).

Comment: "The idea: If we do a better job communicating what we want in a question to new users through a better user experience with some extra help initially, they'll have a better experience by asking better questions." The problem description is fairly obvious and present for a fairly long time already. It's the solution that is complicated and discussed quite controversely. Having said that I'm curious to get to know what the SO team has chosen as a solution for that.

Comment: "Why don't more folks that keep hitting the site from search engines eventually sign up and take on small units of work to help?" Why should they? Just doing the work for others? Where is the benefit for the folks?

Comment: "vision" is a strange way of saying "when you fail at your core mission because you're too busy trying to do a hundred other things" @andras

Comment: I'm on Team DAG, and I voted for the name. :P

Comment: @JeremyBanks Well dang. I mean Dag. I mean... uh... wasn't DAG originally Documentation Analysis Group?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yep. DAG has a funny connotation for Aussies.

Comment: The sentence with *"about the moving parts we have working on things"* does not compute well.

Comment: "Why don't more folks that keep hitting the site from search engines eventually sign up and take on small units of work to help? Why is anonymous feedback so confusing to interpret? What parts of the system make perfect sense to us because we're so used to them, but throw new folks for a total loop?" And most importantly "why don't we the SE team work on ANYTHING that would actually help the folks that do most of the janitorial work?"

Comment: On a lighter-hearted note, you can get the acronym to be DANG by filling in the blank here: Developer Affinity, N_______, and Growth (sadly I can't think of a fitting word)

Comment: "In short, they're going to help to put the responsiveness back into [...] meta" -- now that's a sight for sore eyes! Thanks!

Comment: In response to: *"The ask question page has not been touched in years"* - The (yellow) box with the text/links under the *"How to Ask"* when they ask a question IMHO, needs to contain a few (more) bullets. Ones such as the regularly asked and proverbial *"What have you tried?"*, and *"Have you researched this long enough?"* and *"Have you gone through the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/1415724) before posting?"* as a few examples. That box doesn't contain clear and enough information to have the person **think** first before posting.

Comment: Addendum to my above: I feel that the devs may not be spending enough time concentrating on the "front" end and need to put themselves in a new user's shoes, since they (devs) have been wearing the same pair for too long.

Comment: I love the fact that this is still up... and that there's a lot of stuff in-between all the way to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342779/what-about-the-community-is-toxic-to-new-users/354514 ... Was wondering if there's a more cohesive reflection on the last 3 years somewhere?

Answer (score 75):

As when ["Project {Re,De}duplication"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286329/project-reduplication-of-deduplication-has-begun), billed largely as better duplicate detection, turned out to be ["The thing that Stack Exchange was most interested in was how to recognise when two posts are falsely labeled as duplicates"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296357/159251), this, read closely, seems to be yet more focus on acquiring new users at the expense of veteran contributors.

> ...ensure that all users find...
> Their **primary purpose** *[emphasis mine]* is to help folks quickly find value in becoming long-term contributors...

I already know where it is. I am one of those long-term contributors.  I've been participating, on a daily basis, in ways that make other people **want** to find your site, for the past six years. What is Team DAG doing to ensure that I *continue* to find value in being here? Is that even on the list? There's no real hint of it here, and [elsewhere it is just glossed over](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project/353876#comment497663_353876).

> What parts of the system make perfect sense to us [...] but throw new folks for a total loop?

How about "what parts of the system don't make sense at all, and [trip up even experienced users](https://www.google.com/search?q=very+low+quality+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com)"? Or "...and [trip up the people taking on those 'small units of work'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues) *and* [the folks watching them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332542/why-could-reviewing-questions-with-unobvious-belonging-be-a-reason-for-banning-f#comment383858_332542)"? How about ["what part of the system could use a little tweak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get) to support and reward key contributors"?

> ...making sure that there's plenty of new folks to fill the holes that veteran users leave when they really slow down in participation...

Another option here would have been "making sure that there's plenty of stuff to keep the interest of veteran users so that they don't slow down in participation". This is actually kind of insulting the more I think on it. Granted, *some* fall-off is natural and inevitable, but you could at least *mention* that you want your top contributors to stick around, instead of talking about them like fungible assets.

> ...do a better job communicating what we want in a question to new users [...] they'll have a better experience...

It would have been ***so easy*** for you to just tack on something here about "...and improve overall question quality...". But you didn't. And taken with all the rest, I think that omission is revealing.

I speak only for myself, but I doubt I'm alone: **I'm tired of hearing about what you're doing for new users**. Doubly so when you present it as if it's big exciting news for veteran users.

I will believe that this is going to have positive effects on the site when I see it.*

Until then, I guess my interest here will continue to slowly wane as I find fewer and fewer questions worth reading, upvoting, and/or providing answers for. So, yup, better prepare to fill that hole with the next body.

> Why don't more folks [...] eventually sign up...

"Why do folks keep signing in?" "Why do highly-contributing folks *stop* signing in?"
Ugh, why am I even still here talking?

---

*And I strongly suspect that my measurement of "positive effects on the site" [differs from yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android/349305#comment474701_349305).

Comment: "Ugh, why am I even still here?" Ultimately only you should know that. Probably the advantages still outweigh the disadvantages and/or there is no better alternative existing yet or you have too much time or you are a very nice person.

Comment: @Trilarion sunk cost is a difficult thing.

Comment: That was more about "why I am still here on Meta, spitting into the wind", @Trilarion. I'm not sure that this _directly_ affects my participation on Main. Just _indirectly_, to the extent that it means unaddressed UX pain points and a dearth of fun questions to answer.

Comment: Well, even if Josh doesn't, I do sometimes ask myself why I'm still here on main answering questions, given all of the problems. The answer is quite simple: because, despite their persistent failings to improve anything on the Q&A side, Stack Overflow is still the best that's out there. But resting on your laurels is not a sustainable business strategy, and since I actually *care* about SO (given all that I've invested here), I'd like to see it *succeed* by getting *better*, not simply stagnate. I also want to (continue to) be *proud* of what I've contributed here & what we stand for.

Comment: "Is there even anything else featured right now?" Blog post. Right now only 3 hot meta posts slots available.

Answer (score 42):

What is the scope of the initial wave of Meta-interaction?  We have requests going back *years*; where would you be starting as a baseline, and how would that translate to us seeing action taken on these things?

For context:  [an earlier uber-Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296349/1752480) I had made about the feedback loop needing improved.

Comment: The snarky grump in me wants to answer "current status: *['Smile and wave, boys, smile and wave'](https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder569/500x/30080569/madagascar-penguin-just-smile-and-wave-boys-smile-and-wave.jpg)*". But I'm trying to be a nice person instead ;) It would be awesome if actual community feedback became a priority! So let's hope for the best.

Comment: This doesn't just fall on the new team, this is something the community team needs to get on too. Fortunately, that part of the CR process (digging these things up and at least putting declined or review/deferred on them) is something we can (and should) be doing. What gets picked up, ultimately though is going to be mostly up to the people writing the code, which is DAG. But we can and will do a better job here, and this is why it's exciting to finally have a PM that keeps sole track of it.

Comment: @TimPost Here's a place for the PM to start: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project There are 80 answers each containing important feature requests - these FRs should be prioritized and then the priority list should be announced so that people know what to expect.

Comment: this could be a starting point :-)  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343403/57475

Answer (score 27):

> Why don't more folks that keep hitting the site from search engines eventually sign up and take on small units of work to help? Why is anonymous feedback so confusing to interpret? What parts of the system make perfect sense to us because we're so used to them, but throw new folks for a total loop?

This *sounds* quite self-aware, and hopefully a new ethos for a new initiative. 
 But I feel historically, StackOverflow has rejected nearly any attempt to try features that might have an indirect consequence of a throttle or filter on growth... instead preferring to find ways to build more and more tools that ask volunteers to bear the burden of their expansionism.

And expansionism it has been.  Whether it's ["Why Don't muggle-born wizards use muggle technology to fight death eaters"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/why-dont-muggle-born-wizards-use-muggle-technology-to-fight-death-eaters) or the [seemingly admittedly failed Documentation thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348030/is-documentation-a-failed-experiment) that I pretty much [knew was a bad idea when it was proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304157/211160).

It would be nice if team DAG paid attention to upvoted feature requests and at least *tried* them.  If there's enough time for large hat collecting projects, there should be time for this:

[Pre-flight screening checklist for first/early posts--adaptively pick three items, tune with metrics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item)

Answer (score 18):

Not an answer, but a plea.

Please Please change the name. This is an [Australian word](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=dag%20definition&oq=dag%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5174j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that is used frequently.

> a lock of wool matted with dung hanging from the hindquarters of a sheep.

[more commonly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dag_(subculture)):

> In Australia, it is often used as an affectionate insult for someone
>   who is, or is perceived to be, unfashionable, lacking
>   self-consciousness about their appearance and/or with poor social
>   skills yet affable and amusing. It is also used to describe an
>   amusing, quirky and likeable person (as in, "He's a bit of a dag") and
>   is non-pejorative.

[Paul Hogan in his younger days](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=the%20paul%20hogan%20show&oq=the%20paul%20hogan%20show&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5545j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

[image]

edit:
*I'm actually thinking a Team of Dags would be appropriate for such a nerdy culture*

edit++:
*No I can't take it! Change it please!?!?*

Comment: All I could think of was an 8-Bit Theater strip: http://www.nuklearpower.com/2003/02/01/episode-244-technical-jargon/

Comment: +1 See [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth?cb=1#comment488471_351751) above.

Comment: I think the acronym is just a playful jest.

Comment: Aww please don't change the name, it reminds of of episodes of Neighbours in the 90s!

Comment: @DavidG please, I AM Neighbours in the 70s! lol My sister calls me a dag practically every time we speak. Also idiot is quite popular `idiot==dag`

Comment: I'd rather be a dag than a bogan :) (That's the Building Online Groups And Networks team of course)

Comment: @DavidG aw we often embrace our inner bogan LOLOL In fact I started swearing so much from doing such, that I needed to quite swearing for 2017. Being an Aussie is a dangerous calamity of contradictions!

Comment: If Linus got away with using 'Git', I reckon SO can get away with DAG!

Comment: Haha! What came to my mind was this scene from *Snatch*: https://youtu.be/dQSnua3M2lo?t=46s

Comment: Quick, quick, come up with a new title that abbreviates to DINGLEBERRY.

Comment: I would have expected some of the "USA is not the center of the world, why do you bother us with USA politics" folks to be like "Australia is not the center of the world, why [...]".

Comment: This reminds of [Scott and Charlene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Robinson_and_Charlene_Mitchell). Ahhh simpler times...

Comment: @Liam ah yes, good times, [good times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Times)

Comment: Just as mods have a Diamond, could DAGs have an upside down Club as it looks like a small bunch of grapes?