# Introduce a feature to allow appealing for re-evaluation of an incorrectly downvoted answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, downvotes

Sometimes a user's legitimate answer is being downvoted by others who failed to understand the user's point or because they initially thought it was wrong but didn't bother taking back the downvote on realisation.

This doesn't make much of a difference for answers with high number of upvotes and minimal downvotes and for the high rep users. However, for new users, even a -2 rep can get significant.

So, I request a feature where the unjustly downvoted answer can be put to be reviewed by high rep users. Thus, they can flag the question as 'valid' and the downvotes can be rolled back.

Of course, there should be limitations like only one review appeal, cooldown between next review appeal by the user and the total number of downvotes.

Comment: [I proposed this as a microprivilege two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259077/175248) (with differences to your suggestion, but similar in spirit).  Hopefully, [with DAG coming on board](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351751/1079354), the microprivilege project may get looked at again and we can get an answer as to whether or not CM thinks it's viable.

Comment: like, for example now, I'm getting a barrage of downvotes without any mention as to why. So these are the kind of situations, it will be useful in.

Comment: *"Recently there have been many situations where…"* Links or it didn't happen.

Comment: Your barrage of downvotes is slightly different than the scope that I'm trying to accomplish.  You may have issues with the way your questions are being phrased.  Ask a question here on Meta in regards to one of them, tagged with [meta-tag:specific-question], and ask what can be done to improve it rather than ask the system to make it so that the feedback magically disappears.

Comment: Alright, I will edit that.

Comment: @Makoto actually, this is happening on a question, so this might be a bad case. But I'm talking about answers to a question.

Comment: So one would be able to use this feature to have upvotes of low quality posts rolled back as well too, right?

Comment: Well, that can be done too I guess. @Servy

Comment: Note that the down vote arrow on answers only asks whether the post is useful. It is possible for an answer to be technically correct but still not be useful.

Comment: I've typically interpreted downvotes to an answer as, "the answer is wrong", so you're *definitely* going to want to make a separate post discussing that answer (again with the tag [meta-tag:specific-answer]), as opposed to asking the system to make that feedback magically disappear.  Who knows; the downvotes may *actually* be justified there.

Comment: The best thing you can do (As I see it) is to communicate with the rest of the community - Don't ask and disappear, and come back to it after 5 hours when it's too late. If you see any downvotes try to edit and improve your post, or ask for clarifications in the comments section

Comment: @BSMP I see, fair point. So how about introducing a feature where there can be two different types of downvotes and this can be applied only if the downvote is for 'not helpful'.

Comment: @AlonEitan that's the part where it fails. When you edit your answer and get a technically correct and helpful answer, the downvotes will still remain.

Comment: @HarshithThota But then you're in better chance to have your question upvoted to revert the negative votes, sometime users leave the tab open to see of the OP comes back and improve their post and then revert their downvote (I do it)

Comment: @AlonEitan except that the other users usually leave the question itself. Also, this applies only to an answer, not to a question.

Comment: @HarshithThota When you get enough reputation to cast downvotes (125 rep.) then your votes are equal value as high rep users. New users might just be new to this site, while being professional on the field of the question/answer they downvote.

Comment: @HarshithThota one way to avoid downvotes - verify that code you post actually works and don't answer known duplicates (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998705/run-command-line-in-python-and-save-the-details/44998749#44998749)

Comment: Or if you are answering a question that is an obvious duplicate, put in efforts to make sure that your answer is better than any of the answers in the most common duplicates, since that is often the standard with which the new answer is held up to.

Comment: Well, in principle, I'm not against a review system where perceived bad downvoting could be 'appealed' to a suitable set of high-rep, skilled and experienced developers on SO.  In practice, I'm not sure how it could be managed.  It would be expensive for the appealer, who would presumably have to put up $$$ as an up-front fee and then charged for time.  I'm surprised that the OP here would suggest such a high-cost proposal.

Comment: Maybe if you had more susbstance to your feature-request?  How do you suggest that it is managed and financed?  Presumably, you are willing to fill an executive role in this.  Are you going to personally provide start-up costs?   Will you be paying industry-norm contract rates to the review panels?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Even then, you're better off just posting your new answer on the canonical question.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: and any skilled and experienced developer that sees an incorrectly downvoted answer will just add an upvote. I really see no point in this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's a ludicrous proposal.  The OP obviously expects to have professional engineers waste their free time on silly appeals to grossly bad questions, arguing endlessly on some 'appeal' chatroom, (courtroom), instead of answering good questions.  No skilled and experienced engineer would serve on such a review system for free, (and almost certainly not even if paid $$$/hr).

Answer (score 17):

So the core problem here is your assumption that every high rep user is going to be capable of judging the technical merits of every single post on the site.  That couldn't be further from the truth.  I wouldn't feel qualified to judge the technical merits of even 1% of the answers on this site, and I suspect that whatever definition of "high rep user" you feel would be appropriate, I'd meet it.  I feel pretty confident in speaking for other high rep users in saying that they'd feel similarly.  Most people here, even the highly skilled experts, are still only experts in a handful specific fields, and aren't qualified to judge answers outside of those fields.

Next, you seem to misunderstand the whole idea of voting.  The idea is that each user that feels qualified to provide feedback on the quality of the post provides their own feedback.  Nobody else can say that another user's opinion of a post is right or wrong; it's someone else's opinion.  A user can provide *their own opinion* if they want, but they have no say in how other user's choose to reflect their own opinion (with a very specific exception for voting fraud, which is outside of the scope of this discussion).  If a user comes across a downvoted answer and feels that it's a good answer *they can upvote it*; they don't get to remove the other user's downvote, but they can provide their own vote.  That's how voting works.

Comment: Reply to the first part of the question: When an appeal is made, the answer is put out for review where a group of high rep users should vote to validate it. It's not just a single user. Given how the high rep users have vast amounts of experience and technical know-how, I'm pretty sure an unanimous decison would more likely be a just one than not. 

As for the second half, I do agree that the votes are opinionated and hence, this problem is more significant in less popular questions which fresh users are less likely to visit. Thus, the user can do nothing about an unjust downvote.

Comment: @HarshithThota And as a high rep user, I'm telling you that that's not the case.  If someone asked me to judge whether a downvote on some random C question was merited, I'd tell you that **I have no idea**, and that I don't feel qualified to judge it.  Same same for a Unity question, or a Python question.  I simply have no expertise in those subjects.  I feel confident that other high rep users would say exactly the same thing about any question not in their area of expertise (which is the overwhelming majority of questions).

Comment: @HarshithThota so wait.... if I downvote you because I find your answer not USEFUL... 5 (or 10, or whatever number you choose) can decide that I was wrong in saying your answer is not useful IN MY EYES?.... that feels like an intellocracy, but with rep....

Comment: @Servy what if the appeal is visible only to the high rep users with a significant amount of rep in tag of the question?

Comment: @HarshithThota It will likely become a problem of scale at that point: are there enough users with enough rep in that tag that are even interested in reviewing to handle the number of appeal flags? (This isn't taking into consideration the other issue of what voting means.)

Comment: @HarshithThota And regardless, if a high rep user in that tag feels that the answer is a good answer, *they can upvote it*.  There's no reason for them to remove the downvote, they can just cast their own vote.  They have then reflected their own opinion on the quality of the answer.

Comment: @Patrice if it is not useful to you but can be useful to many others who haven't seen the answer yet that's when this works. Moreover, the feature just lets you make the appeal, not go through it without review

Comment: @HarshithThota By downvoting the user is indicating that think the post *isn't* going to be useful for other people.  You can of course disagree with them, and cast your own vote to reflect that, but again, that doesn't give you the right to take away *their* opinion.

Comment: @HarshithThota if I vote and say "I don't think this is useful", I don't think anyone can go "YES IT IS" and force my vote to be removed. "usefulness" is subjective, and that is okay. I don't think ANY number of users should be able to overwrite a subjective vote like this. Your answer can be functional... doesn't mean it's useful. This review cannot work for a subjective criteria like usefulness. And btw, I disagree that even if reviewed this is okay. My vote is my own, and my opinion shouldn't be overwritten

Comment: @HarshithThota additionally if you force high rep users to look at your regular garden variety post you likely get downvotes and "downvote was justified" - I'd personally consider such request as "my question/answer deserves to be top post - please upvote" and review it accordingly... Just pretend your post has downvote and put as much effort as you can before posting it (including research if similar questions were asked/answered to avoid duplicate questions or answers).

Comment: Since the 'high-rep users' are being tasked to review questions and votes, I'm still waiting to find out how these skilled and experienced developers on the review panel will get paid for their time?