# Can we make tag synonyms of [nsnotification] and [nsnotifications]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I noticed yesterday that there are two tags: [nsnotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotification) and [nsnotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotifications), each with 300-400 questions. From reading the tag descriptions, it didn't sound like there was any difference between these two:

> NSNotification objects encapsulate information so that it can be broadcast to other objects by an NSNotificationCenter object.
>
> NSNotification is a class used to send messages to observing classes through NSNotificationCenter.

It seems like either one should be removed or at the very least, they should be tag synonyms.

Comment: This tag pair is part of [this list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/4642212).

Comment: So it is! But per the comments, it's unclear what's supposed to happen. Should I just go ahead and make the tag change? Or is there some sort of process or preferred order for the changes?

Comment: Just for the record, the tag synonym was created by Chris Hanson on Nov 23 '10 at 2:34, but it was never approved for the past 8 years. Approved it now, in the same way as it was proposed. If you need it swapped, let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addressing another issue, SE caused the problem with fixing this problem, and the related 'hyphenation' one, *more than six years ago* and have done *almost* nothing to remedy it since. The exception is that [@♦animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) merged a few handfuls some years ago.

Despite [@♦Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post)'s assurances ([eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351751/1505120)):

> It's also the DAG team's job to make sure that Q&A gets what it needs, approximately when it needs it, and as it stands against all of
>   the goals that the team is trying to meet.
>
> They also ensure that community requests get scheduled, discussed and
>   many times ultimately status-completed or at least status-deferred if
>   we love an idea but just can't act on it right now.
>
> In short, they're going to help to put the responsiveness back into
>   the mix of the meta and mayhem that can be a big part of actively
>   participating in features and bugs.

there is not even a pink tag on this Q.

So, as usual, [*On n'est jamais servi si bien que par soi-même*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-Guillaume_%C3%89tienne). However, standard users do not have access to the tools *that are available* to make the remediation process other than extremely painful. Mods *do* have access to these tools and [Bhargav Rao♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) has, very recently, done **splendid** work - in the space of just a few days (for roughly `40` pairs about as long as it took me to deal with just one (`1`), and the simplest one (`1`) at that).

However *none* of our other mods seem inclined 'to lend a hand' (I specifically suggested such activity to one of them) and there is, of course, the usual argument that "mods are too busy" (the one that pairs up with "we don't need more mods"). Not too busy however for writing things like this [instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373158/1505120):

> For many people it's ineffective tools. For others it's a lack of
>   consultation. For other it's feeling ignored with a focus on the
>   newuser that precludes the needs of the regulars. The rights or wrongs
>   are unimportant, what we need to find are solutions. People want to
>   know what unit is the 6-8? weeks, months, years? People need to feel
>   heard.
>
> One thing I am aware of is the network is listening closely. This is
>   why I'm posting this. To give people a chance to speak up and say. Hey
>   this is what I need. This is what we need.

So all we are left with is a tedious, one post at a time, retagging if this mess from six years ago (it is a 'once off', not recurrent issue) is to be fixed. Instead of one fix per tag pair at the tag level (mod-only option) there may be over 22,000 edits required at the Q level (standard user option) for a single tag pair (though thankfully not for this specific instance).

When making those edits be wary of "front-page flooding". Dribbled into the system whatever the requirement was to start with it will turn out to be greater before complete - ie further Qs will be mistagged in the same way before a tag can be auto-removed.

Also, be aware that while mods are excused comprehensive edits when synonymising etc, standard users are not. So each retag may also require edits to the Qs other than for tags.

And, the plural form is favoured.

Please do get stuck in right away, and Good Luck!