# Does "Where developers learn, share, and build careers" need an update?

Tags: discussion

With the demise of job postings and the developer story, there isn't really any "build careers" part of Stack Overflow anymore, is there? It is time to update the slogan?

Comment: But careers can be built just by using the site and learning skills from this usage. Having said that, I have to wonder if this might be somewhat of a pedantic debate, like asking for the number of angels dancing on the head of a pin.

Comment: And just because jobs is gone, doesn't mean SO has lost "leverage" with employers. There's still a number of companies that consider SO reputation when hiring, tying rep straight to career building. Some recruiters also browse users on SO to find people to hire

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Can you list some of those employers please? Asking for a friend...

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I once applied to a cloud hosting company and they asked for my SO profile to check on my rep (I did not get the job, for other reasons). Not sure why it seems so unbelievable that employers would look at that.

Comment: Having "build careers" because it *might* indirectly help your career makes about as much sense as "make friends" would in the same context.

Comment: Its a marketing slogan, so it doesn't really have to make actual sense :) It just needs to sound funky.

Comment: but but SO reputation can help you get a job, right?

Comment: Maybe. But idiots like me can build up a pretty decent amount of rep.

Comment: It lasted 5 years: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351540/where-do-developers-learn-share-build-their-career

Comment: @Marco13 Your link cites a doozy of a comment from SO's "product manager on the new Developer Affinity and Growth team" (at that time in 2017, with my emphasis added): _"Developer Affinity = **Developer engagement and love. Our team's charter is to continue building on the love that developers have for SO.** Our team is still new and in the early stages, but it is safe to assume our plans will include improvements in the Q&A experience that provide compelling value for signing up and staying signed in"._ I can't imagine them trying that hogwash now.

Comment: If we’re being nitpicky, people don’t seem to learn here much either; copy-pasting ready-made solutions hardly counts as ‘learning’.

Comment: I'm sort of surprised this was at all controversial. It seemed obvious to me that it's just a bit of an oversight. Previously SO was directly wanting to support developers' career-building activities, through the form of the CV (later Developer Story) and helping connect them with potential employers, and even applying for jobs. They've moved out of that market now, and the slogan needs to change to reflect that.

Comment: @SteveBennett That's an assumption. I know how commercial Stack Overflow is under the hood, the slogan as it is to me sounds exactly like what they want it to be. there is absolutely no direct link in it to any kind of service, it's just ambiguous sunshine and rainbows phrasing. The "build careers" part can still refer to the fact that Stack Overflow is an important factor in the average developer's working day. I can't deny that Stack Overflow has potentially saved me from days of manual labor to root out a problem on several occasions. That speedy resolve reflects well on me.

Comment: That slogan is on the homepage, which is reached when you haven't logged in, which is very rare even for non-logged in people for you either are already logged in when you open the page or you Google and open the question page directly. I personally came across that page only once in my life.. 4 years ago

Comment: @khelwood Having "build careers" because there are job postings makes about as much sense as "build houses" does on a real estate agent's website.

Comment: We the product of the United States...

Comment: What I'd want: "where developers compile, debug and build programs". What would suit better: "where students beg, steal or borrow their homework".

Comment: "Where developers come to get roasted"

Comment: @Lundin I've never compiled any programs on StackOverflow. Does it support C99?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I heard that there might be jokes as well as sarcasms there though.

Comment: @skomisa That link dates back to the time surrounding 'welcominggate', and there certainly had been no shortage of hogwash back then. I left the main site in the meantime, but it's hard to imagine that they fired all the people who led SO on the wrong track. Insofar, all this doesnt's really matter - it's just some title of some website, FWIW...

Comment: @Marco13 Yes indeed, emphasis at the time was pretty much "_MUST_ welcome homework questions or Twitter is gonna tweet", also known as Twitter-Driven Development. Actually, those who were prominently pushing for the welcome wagon have left the company by now.

Comment: *"Where students outsource their homework"*

Answer (score 28):

The current phrase is a slogan that's displayed as the main site title and (to me) feels disconnected from reality, which was invented by someone from SO and pushed through without asking the community. So if you're asking for an update, you're practically asking for the SO marketing department or management to invent a new slogan.

Disregarding the fact that there is no *need* to update a slogan, as it has no effect on how the site works and was never anything but feel-good fluff, I think precedent shows that SO has little interest in community input here. The current slogan was decided without any community consultation, and IIRC the community wasn't even given any notice that the slogan changed. Furthermore, given that SO ignored the community outrage when they rolled out the front page changes, along with many other complaints about similar endeavors (e.g. the blog, #soreadytohelp, "social" features), I doubt anything meta says will have an effect on how SO marketing operates.

That said, if you want to spend time to make up a new slogan and propose it to SO, feel free to do so. You could create a new meta Q/A pair for a slogan contest and we could all vote for the least bad option (using words such as "good" for marketing fluff would be a stretch IMO). If anybody at SO would care about that is however not answerable by the community.

Comment: StackOverflow: Wikipedia the game.

Comment: [StackOverflow: The FLAMETHROWER!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgRFQJCHcPw)

Comment: Stack Overflow: Goodhart’s law, the website.

Comment: Stack-Overflow, not for homework (or not a code-writing service, whichever feels appropriate)

Comment: Stack Overflow - Process returned 139 (0x8B).

Comment: StackOverflow: how to edit page tittle?

Comment: StackOverflow: Tanks in Advance

Answer (score 18):

Stack Overflow was a factor in getting me my current job, even without the assistance of the job board.  The interviewers were impressed with my contributions to the site.

Comment: It might also work against you, showing that you spend vast amounts of time doing Stack Overflow stuff instead of working :) Me personally, I keep my Stack Overflow account completely detached from my work. It's personal data as far as I am concerned, nobody needs to know.

Comment: I mention my rep (small as it is, still top 6% which impresses folks who don't realize the shape of the rep curve) on my resume, but no link or my handle here.  I list it under "Community and Volunteering," because this is quite literally volunteer work in an online community.

Comment: @TomServo I can understand not mentioning SO on your resume at all, and I can understand linking to your SO handle in your resume, but I can't understand choosing to mention SO on your resume, but deliberately remaining anonymous. How is that helpful for the person looking at your resume?

Comment: @skomisa Those who've asked about my contribution here have always asked something like "cool, what do you focus on there," etc.  Kind of like, "oh you volunteer your time to charity ___ , cool," and then move on.  No one has ever asked for my handle to research my profile and answers.  At the level I'm at (tech exec, 32 years in the business, bought my first computer in 1979), people probably just consider it a charitable hobby.  If I had 200,000+ rep it might be different.  I sometimes claim, "My hobby is more technical than the role I'm interviewing for. Smiling, of course.  :)

Comment: @skomisa I don't think it's any less helpful than "I have x years doing y". It shows you have experience and allows them to ask more questions about it if they wish. Which if they're interested is good for you and you haven't had to give away personal information (like if you'd asked a question on workplace about an issue you had at work)

Comment: @SamDean It's a fair point that if you give the prospective employer a link to your SO handle, they can read absolutely everything that you have ever posted, or at least everything which is still accessible. I hadn't considered the issue from that perspective.

Comment: @Gimby, as long as we tell the employers we won't be using their time to moderate SO or post here on SO (unless its something work related which is very rarely allowed to be posted on SO and that too, at least in my case, needs a separate account) we should be fine. What we do on our personal time is none of their business.

Answer (score 6):

I did a mid-career pivot into Software engineering primarily based on maintaining an open source software product. And Stack Overflow was the primary place I learned how to find the information I needed, how to properly apply best practices, and what problems the community was trying to find software to solve.

So yes, I built my career with significant help from Stack Overflow, and continue to do so as I expand my career in new directions.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418713/does-where-developers-learn-share-and-build-careers-need-an-update?noredirect=1#comment915108_418713

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418713/does-where-developers-learn-share-and-build-careers-need-an-update/418732?noredirect=1#comment915268_418713