# Answer is incorrect, what to do?

Tags: discussion

A fairly simple question was asked and someone answers the question with syntax errors and invalid code.

Either this is OPs second account or he is equally clueless because this answer got accepted.

What to do?
Should we accept that SO has an incorrect answer as the accepted one?
I tried to use the flag as not an answer but it was declined with this explanation: *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*.

Link to answer: [Max Amount of Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747037/max-amount-of-loops/49747092#49747092)

Comment: [Duty called](https://xkcd.com/386/)  With -3 it already isn't going to impress any future visitors.  You can heap on one more.

Comment: you should downvote and comment

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought my comments was visible, but yes I have commented and downvoted

Comment: yes saw it ;) and I added my downvote and my delete vote as the code is clearly wrong and the answer should not be accepted. The good answer is below it.

Comment: that's a not so subtle use of the meta effect...

Comment: I clicked on the link and I was surprised to find your answer is also downvoted! Can you guess why? I am not good in PHP so I do not know whats going on @Andreas

Comment: @Xenolion no idea why. It's a working method and in my opinion I have explained the code. It was downvoted after  I posted here so it's probably someone who has read here and downvoted me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The wrong answer being accepted wouldn't be a problem, but the accepted answer is always shown first, so it can mislead some readers. See [unpinning the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) for a more general discussion about that. On the other hand only OP can decide which answer is accepted.

So it is really important when you notice a wrong accepted answer, to downvote it, so that people can see the negative score, and move on to the next answer. In the linked example case, this has already happened, so there is no need to pile-on more downvotes. Note also the the author of an answer cannot delete it if accepted, so he has no way to fix the situation other than editing it into shape (or flagging the answer for moderation).

Users with more than 20K reputation points can vote to delete a negatively scored answer, if it is so wrong that it is unsalvageable, or if it misses the point of the question entirely, etc.