# Change the symbol for the accepted answer so people don't assume it's the only correct answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

There seems to be constant confusion about what the green check mark actually means. Although it's meant to indicate which [answer best helped the asker](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) with their question, many people think it indicates which [answer best helped the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304025/does-stack-overflow-have-a-special-google-integration)* or worse, [an indication of the *only* correct answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365699/why-cant-we-choose-multiple-correct-answers). I regularly see comments like, "This should be the accepted/checked answer".

I think the symbol being a check mark makes people think "correct" instead of "accepted".

However, we don't get that same confusion with bounties. People seem to understand that the bounty mark is only an indication that the bounty giver liked that answer best** and therefore gave that answerer some extra reputation points.

Since this is also how we want visitors to view the accepted answer, why not replace the green check mark with something that looks more like the badge for bounties? I'm thinking the same small rounded rectangle with the number of reputation points except it's:

- Green
- It has a heart instead of a plus sign to indicate it's the pinned answer (heart instead of thumbtack suggested by duplode)

---

*You can't tell from that particular screenshot but Google was indicating the accepted answer as the "Best Answer" regardless of score.

**It can also mean it was the most popular answer at the time if it was automatically awarded but you can't tell that by looking.

Comment: I agree a bit and I think the suitable solution is to make the *votes* tab work by votes and not make the accepted the first on then filter the remaining by votes. Doing that we will always have the most upvoted answer on the top and the accepted one can be lower. I don't think changing the check mark will change the perception, after all it is an image and each one may have it's own interpretation

Comment: @TemaniAfif _“each one may have it's own interpretation”_ — the accept icon has even been referred to as [“pipe icon”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/360192/1) once.

Comment: @Xufox haha, nice one :p ... Maybe someone will also refer the accepted icon to this user https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals :p

Comment: I like this idea. It shows other users that the accepted answer is just that, the answer accepted by OP. It may not be the best answer, it sometimes may not be even a working answer! Particularly, I'd go with something like this: https://imgur.com/a/DXvGqmt (from one of my answers). This is an SVG of the same size of the tick, which is 40x40 px.

Comment: @Xufox I actually kinda like that. Perhaps those among us who dislike the importance granted to the check mark should start calling it "the pipe", as a form of protest...

Comment: On first read, I agree with you. There's always room for improvement. As I understand the function of the site similarly as you do, I see your suggestion as an improvement. However, on further thought, we come here to learn how things work. Changing how the site function because some people refuse to learn how it works may or may not have unintended consequences.

Comment: Any change needs to be a clear improvement. -- Haha, "The Pipe"; usually a negative connotation. -- One thing about the ♥️ suggestion (below) is that there are different types: ❤️ the first being simply "chosen", the second "chosen and some trending popularity", the third indicating that **another answer** scores far greater UpVotes (the OP is *wrong*), and the fourth indicating "chosen and highly upvoted". Use a simple symbol that can convey many different meanings, all within a small area. That doesn't mean I support the change, but if the improvement is clear ...

Comment: "_assume_"? We never told them that, why should we change?

Comment: What I've seen _a lot of times_ is that not-very-knowledgeable OP accepts the answer that he/she understands best, not the best one. Sometimes the _worst_ one.

Comment: I guess "the pipe" makes sense: when I see the poor quality of some of the accepted answers I wonder what the OP was smoking. :)

Comment: But seriously, Stack Exchange regulars know that the accepted answer may not be the best one. After all, the OP is often the least-informed contributor to a page, so we generally can't expect them to have the expertise necessary to select the very best answer. But casual visitors don't understand this, and I don't think a simple cosmetic change to the "accept" icon will make much of an impact on that.

Comment: There can be a set of answers with slightly different side effects. Which one is "the best" then depends on what it is used for.

Comment: I'm restarting an internal debate about how we currently handle accepted answers, and all of the problems a lack of graceful information deprecation is creating (and will create for enterprise eventually too). I'm going to use this as one of the talking points. Please take this comment to be an implied `status-deferred`, I'm not putting that tag on this because this isn't the idea we're actually deferring, it's just really good evidence that this is never going to start coming up and we should just do something about it even if it's scary.

Comment: Maybe the tick could be changed to a star, and the favourite icon to a heart? We used to get stars in school for good work.

Answer (score 23):

While I instinctively like this idea, [Nicol Bolas also has a point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366514/2751851). As long as the accepted answer is pinned, choosing it is kind of a big deal, and it makes sense for question authors to perceive it as such. That being so, as long as there isn't a change of heart about the [status-declined] of [*Please unpin the accepted answer from the top*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/2751851), changes in the presentation of acceptance should be evaluated according not just to its effect on readers, but also on question authors.

A few more disjointed thoughts:

- I also agree with Nicol about a thumbtack making the choice feel a little too arbitrary. In the end, pinning is just a by-effect of acceptance.
- While the pre-acceptance tooltip of the checkmark shown to question authors is "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution [...]", the post-acceptance tooltip shown to readers is much cruder: "The question owner accepted this as the best answer [...]".
- As far as I'm aware of, the only SE site that does something significantly different when it comes to displaying acceptance is MathOverflow ([arbitrary example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295920)). I find the green background quite elegant, but unfortunately adopting that wouldn't free us from choosing an icon -- both because of accessibility concerns and of the need for something for question authors to click on.
- It seems tricky to pick a good, simple alternative icon that conveys acceptance with the nuances you put forward here. A star (as in "This is the question author's favourite answer") would make some sense, but it would, to an extent, clash with the other use of a star icon here. A thumbs-up would bring in way too much baggage to be helpful, in my opinion. From the possibilities I could think of while writing this, the only one I somewhat like is a *heart*, because it would more clearly convey that acceptance is a personal choice of the question author...

  - Some alternative suggestions, collected from the comments: a badge labelled "Asker's Choice" ([Ajedi32](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366512/change-the-symbol-for-the-accepted-answer-so-people-dont-assume-its-the-only-c/366522?noredirect=1#comment578423_366522)); switching the favourite icon to a heart and using a star for acceptance ([Andrew Morton](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366512/change-the-symbol-for-the-accepted-answer-so-people-dont-assume-its-the-only-c/366522?noredirect=1#comment579310_366512)).

Comment: Yeah, I don't feel particularly strongly that it needs to be a thumbtack. I just knew it couldn't be a check mark (makes the change pointless) or a star (you already pointed out why). But it also couldn't be nothing because then it'd look *exactly* like a bounty. Won't change the main point of contention but I'll edit the post to suggest a heart.

Comment: If you put a heart next to an answer then I will forever ponder "when the heck did I favorite this?"

Comment: How about just a badge labeled "Asker's Choice" or something to that effect? Or maybe just add that text to the existing checkmark?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Would the heart being green (as opposed to the usual red heart/yellow star) dispel that effect a bit?

Comment: @Ajedi32 I like the badge idea. A badge with ribbons -- [a little like this one, but green] -- might be a good fit.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I think that suggestion is worthy of its own answer

Comment: *for question authors to perceive it as such* — what if it was only pinned to the top for the question asker?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Then the feature would be of negligible value anyway.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is *supposed to be* correct. That's the ideal. If you're looking at the question, and it has an accepted answer, you ought to be able to use that and go. That's what the feature is for.

By changing the checkmark to something else, you're effectively admitting that the accepted answer shouldn't be seen as anything particularly special. That it's no more "correct" just because the person who asked the question (in theory, the person most familiar with the problem) indicated that it was "correct". At which point, you may as well not make the accepted answer the first visible answer (when viewing by votes, which is the default).

So really, this suggestion is really just a restatement of the idea of diminishing the importance of accepted answers.

Comment: Perhaps I worded the request poorly but you've misunderstood me. I'm not saying the accepted answer shouldn't be seen as correct at all. I'm saying it shouldn't be seen as the *only* correct answer or that acceptance was something the *community* did. I'm not complaining that the accepted answer has importance, I'm pointing out that the meaning being ascribed to it is wrong.

Comment: @BSMP: "*I'm saying it shouldn't be seen as the only correct answer or that acceptance was something the community did.*" I don't see how being a green checkmark indicates either of those things. And turning it into a pin reduces the importance of acceptance. It isn't "correct"; it's merely something someone stuck in front of everyone else's answers.

Comment: Related: [Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095)

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Generally, most people treat "you ought to be able to use that and go" and "the only correct answer" to mean the same thing. I've seen a fair number of users ask duplicates of existing questions, saying "the answer to this dupe doesn't work" when they really mean "the accepted answer to this dupe doesn't work, and I haven't bothered to look at any of the other answers because the accepted answer is the only one that's relevant as far as I'm concerned".

Comment: @BoltClock: We can't control what people do; we can only give them information and let them make their own choices. I don't see how a pin will make the proper impression any better. Remember: the goal of acceptance is to mark the answer that the asker of the question feels solves the problem. A pin merely communicates that the asker stuck this question here for some reason.

Comment: No, accepted answer is not supposed to be _correct_, it's supposed to be the _most helpful one at the time of the acceptance_.

Comment: @Cœur: How can the answer be helpful if it is not *correct*? Correctness is an important aspect of any helpful answer. Also, I don't see how a pin indicates helpfulness.

Comment: @NicolBolas either because "partially correct, partially incorrect", or "totally incorrect, but gives a hint of which command to use", or "was correct in the past, but not anymore".

Comment: @Cœur According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), acceptance "simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally". While it is possible for an answer that "worked" not to be entirely correct, "most helpful one at the time of the acceptance" is too low a bar -- for one, it is not usually expected of question authors to accept the most helpful between two mostly unhelpful answers.

Comment: @duplode see the comment on this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317739/hibernate-could-not-execute-query-exception

Comment: @Cœur The guidelines suggest the question author there should not have accepted that answer.

Comment: @Cœur: Yay, you found one instance from almost a decade ago of a person using acceptance incorrectly. In that time, how many upvotes have their been on clearly garbage answers? Nobody's claiming that every accepted answer is perfect. But if there is any widespread misconception about how the feature should be used, I still fail to see how a thumbtack is going to improve things.

Comment: All that talk about the Help Center article and the various interpretations thereof is precisely why suggestions like this and previous suggestions of diminishing or removing the acceptance feature exist. If you have to look in the Help Center to understand what the checkmark means because it doesn't mean what most people think it means (based on their understanding of it in everyday usage), the feature is seriously flawed.

Comment: @BoltClock: We don't remove features because people don't always agree on their meaning. We don't get rid of the "lacks MCVE" close reason because some users keep asking questions without MCVEs. And I contend that, generally speaking, people do interpret the acceptance check correctly. The fact that some people occasionally don't doesn't change the fact that *most* do.

Comment: IME, it's not unusual to see accepted answers that are wrong, i.e., the code doesn't generate the desired result. For example, yesterday I saw a question where the OP wanted code for a loop to print all the even integers from 0 to 100. The code in the accepted answer just prints the string "even" 50 times. :(  I wouldn't be surprised if there were accepted answers containing code that's supposed to be runnable code that doesn't even run.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Your point is merely a restatement of what I said in my answer: you're arguing to *remove* acceptance as a feature (or rather, diminish it into irrelevance, but that's the same thing), not that acceptance is being interpreted incorrectly. The user who accepted the "even" answer probably genuinely believed that it solved his problem... somehow.

Comment: I don't want to remove acceptance, or make it irrelevant, but I do think it would be good if it's importance could be reduced. However, I don't think merely changing the icon would have much of an impact on that. OTOH, I _like_ it when my answers are accepted. :)

Comment: _"the person who asked the question (in theory, the person most familiar with the problem)"_ and least familiar with the solution

Answer (score 13):

This (and many other ideas) surrounding ways to make the accepted answer more useful, or less dangerous depending on what you're looking at, are things that make a big problem a *little* better.

The big problem in the room is that we have no strategy to deal with information deprecation and that problem is only going to get bigger. Not only are we inconsistent with how the accepted answer works (remember, self-accepts don't get pinned!), we're pretty jittery right now when it comes to anything that could (however inadvertently) make engagement KPIs go wonky while working on things that we're already sure are going to make engagement KPIs go wonky.

I suspect that [Nicol Bolas is essentially correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366514/50049), and I might go on to say that our reluctance thus far to deprecate the accept feature has led to our failure to more gracefully deprecate outdated information.

I think the solution here is to ultimately change "accept" to be more literal in a manner that doesn't automatically imply that *anyone* tested it, and not let it influence the sort order any longer. Perhaps, if there is an accepted answer, we just provide a means to skip to it. This is essentially where we left off the last time we <strike>threw chairs at each other</strike> talked about such a fundamental change to it, so we'll pick it up.

But, it's going to need to wait until we're done with other stuff that causes us to closely monitor engagement metrics, as we couldn't rule such a major change out as a cause, and would need to do so only when such a change could happen intrinsically, or isolated from others.

Consider this (and others like it) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now, and I'm going to share this with correspondence to restart the conversation, but the ultimate deferred action is what to do with the accept mark altogether.

Comment: "we have no strategy to deal with information deprecation" actually we have. The help center explicitly states that one reason to edit post is to update them. Some very vocal members of the community decided that they do not want anybody to edit anything but formatting. Then they proceeded to paint themselves in a corner arguing that reviewers need not to have knowledge of the post they are reviewing to evaluate suggested edits. That behavior then leaks to 2kers and get enforced.

Comment: Once you get stronger wording out that such edits are welcomed and that reviewers are required **to have knowledge of the thing they are reviewing** would be a huge step towards that. Also, it would help [toward the low turnover of the queues.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288121/213575)

Comment: And by stronger wording I meant actual action.

Comment: @Braiam (this is a very honest question and in no way rhetorical) do you really think we could write encouragement _strongly_ enough for people to essentially put a whole new answer over someone else's user card? That's .. kinda where it gets stuck, people are _really_ reticent to do that, and it all gets complicated mostly because that's ruled out. I'm with you 100%, I just don't know how we'd get people to actually do it.

Comment: Well, I would say that you actually don't need that. People would just do it. To be then told off that that shouldn't be done. The later is the thing you should actually prevent, the former will naturally happen.

Comment: BTW, I am pretty terrible to detect rhetoric.

Comment: The feature request wasn't about obsolescence but I guess that's moot at this point.

Answer (score 6):

This checkmark (plus the fact that the answer appears on top of the page, but that's another story) makes it look like it's the best answer, whereas it's the best answer *in OP opinion*. A single person opinion, that is (it may not even be the best answer to OP problem, just the answer OP understands)

When we think of it, the accepted +15 rep points is a bit like a "free bounty" that OP awards to the answer which he/she likes most.

So why not using a +15 bounty-like *green* rectangle, with a tooltip saying "this is the accepted answer" when hovering over it ?

Comment: I think duplode 3rd list item makes a good point that we still need a symbol due (or at least something other than color) to distinguish it from a bounty due to [accessibility concerns](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast).

Comment: good point. rounded-corner rectangle? besides it's not possible to have a 15-rep bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the "answer that best helped the community" would be the one with the most upvotes.

NB Maybe it would be better defined as "answer that best helped the segment of the community who log in and have enough rep to upvote" - which is not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a non-issue.

If people are exclaiming that:

> This should be the accepted/checked answer

then they probably need a refresh of hovering the green checkmark which reads "The question owner accepted this as the best answer".

---

If anything, default the sorting to "Votes" and do not apply "sticky accepted answers" **BUT** do provide a setting so that I can enable "sticky accepted answers" for myself.

Do take this suggestion with a grain of salt because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326106/2191572 has some thoroughly valuable points.

Answer (score -2):

There is already a mechanic to deal with incorrect, inaccurate, and outdated answers. The down vote. It would be a much better effort to **encourage people to down vote** than to change something that has been a mechanic for 10 years.

The vocal minority that promotes a culture promotes down votes as *rude* and insists that it is a personal offence that you can even down vote anything to begin with much less without an explanation get so much validation it stops the system from working as it is designed.

We need a *Summer of Love of Quality* campaign to promote and encourage active down voting of poor content.

Something with dozens of down votes will make it really clear that the green check mark should be ignored.

Comment: But this feature request isn't about incorrect, inaccurate, and outdated answers. This is about people perceiving the check mark to be a community decision versus the asker's decision.