# How to deal with obsolete and wrong answer without editing / flagging?

Tags: discussion, support, old-answers

I have come across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026337/how-do-i-get-link-to-an-image-on-wikipedia-from-the-infobox/) (the accepted one) that was rendered wrong and obsolete by a change of Wikimedia content usage. I tried to deal with this answer in various ways, but unfortunately all of them failed:

- I tried to flag the answer which resulted in my flag being rejected
  [image: Screenshot of raised flag and rejection rationale]
- I tried to add my own answer, but it didn't receive any upvotes in more than a year and hence there was little reason to think that anyone would even read it. Therefore, I self-deleted the answer and...
- I tried to suggest an edit that would update the accepted answer, but this edit was rejected as well.
  [image: Screenshot of suggested edit and rejection rationales]

What is the correct way to handle this situation? I tried to search the Meta for some ideas and most of the relevant answers suggest editing or deleting the obsolete answer, both of which I tried to do.

Comment: Comment / vote / post another answer. Nothing more to do. That your answer wasn't receiving upvotes do not necessarily mean you had to _delete_ it. You could have edited to improve it. And give it time. Votes do not always come as often as one would like.

Comment: Adding your own answer was the right thing to do I think.  But note the most upvoted answer on that question already mentions hotlinking.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, but it doesn't include any information about Special:FilePath which allows hotlinking without unnecessarily complicated usage of md5.

Comment: @Magma then undelete your answer; if it's better, and the question is common, you'll get the upvotes eventually.

Comment: @snakecharmerb My alternative answer was posted in May 2017 and I suspect no one even read it since was naturally sticked at the bottom below 4 alternative answers. Now it may be different with the Meta effect, but this still doesn't quite solve the general problem. It just seems wrong to leave the obviously wrong answer at the very top of the page...

Comment: The accepted answer in this case only has 1 upvote. The answer below that has 12 upvotes. Once you gain downvote privileges you can downvote the answer to reflect the unhelpful answer. People will scroll down eventually to the helpful, upvoted answers.

Comment: @Codeer The other answers under the post are unfortunately outdated as well since they deal with the problem in a rather complicated way (deriving the file path using md5) instead of using the Special:FilePath (which was presumably introduced later to simplify the process)

Comment: Again, the tools at your disposal are commenting, voting (although your down-votes do not yet affect the post score since you have less than 125 rep), and **posting**. Fundamentally changing the existing answers is up to the posts owners.

Comment: Are you just talking about accepted answers here or all answers? The solution for the latter case is straightforward - just down-vote. Down-voting accepted answers is, while still useful, not as obvious as the answer still sticks to the top of the list.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

When accepted answers contain erroneous information, I take exception. Because accepted answers bypass SO's ordering-by-votes feature. Unpinning accepted answers is a [long-standing feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) which has been declined.

Comments are ephemeral. In this case, an upvoted comment from 2010 has not caused the answer to be updated. I've gone ahead and [edited the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1027444/revisions) myself with quoted documentation. That comment <s>can now be</s> has been flagged as "No longer required".

Your edit was rejected presumably because it completely transformed the answer. Meanwhile, my edit:

1. Separates the original answer from the reference to the latest documentation.
2. Reflects information contributed in a well-received comment.

Comment: My hot take is that two wrongs don't make a right. I'd still choose to voice the long-standing feature request harder than make edits that conflict with the original author's intent.

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays, In my view, I'm not "conflicting with the original author's intent." I'm leaving the author's content in tact and *adding additional information* from the comments, explicitly separating the two parts.

Comment: "Your edit was rejected presumably because it completely transformed the answer" — exactly why I rejected it. Your edit is much better.