# Degrading votes

Tags: feature-request

I've come across many old questions with an accepted answer that has since become obsolete since its acceptance.

What ends up happening is it becomes answer posters responsibility to maintain and update the answer, after someone comments how the solution is obsolete, and you get 2000 word essays with 5 different answers. They've essentially parked their spot on that answer forever.

Also, sometimes the OP doesnt even mark the best answer as the accepted one.

If SO were to degrade votes over time, and also not place the accepted answer as the first result, users would benefit from getting the best current solution, without having to scroll through, making SO more convenient to reference.

---

Remarks

Questions are rarely for some specific version, so I don't know why everyone keeps bring this argument of `its still valid for that users scenario`. The *majority* of question are generic enough to evolve over time. I.e:

> "How do I append a string to a buffer in *LANGUAGE*"

It can remain the accepted answer but it's no longer useful to prioritise this answer over a newer up-to-date solution.

If you're arguing that the question should become obsolete, as opposed to accepted answer, then you'd be promoting the duplication of questions...

I'm not in favour of the answerer having to maintain their post - but was using it as an example of the pitfall of the current implemntation. The problem is, the new answers won't get seen, because the 10 year old answer is hogging space. The accepted answer can remain as thats what the user accepted at the time, but for future reference it's not helpful seeing these dated answers. And it will also alleviate the need for the original poster to continuously edit the question over the years. Someone else can just come and post the answer (as opposed to leaving a comment and hoping the answer poster updates their answer), and naturally it will flow upwards.

Comment: I am sure this has been asked a few days back, but I can't find the dupe

Comment: Regarding the second part of your idea, there is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) dupe. I'm sure there is a dupe for the first part, but I can't find it either.

Comment: For the first part, wouldn't it be [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384697/1197934)?

Comment: It's certainly very closely related, as its dupe targets and related questions. Although not a dupe, IMO

Comment: This is only if you wrongly assume that answers become obsolete. But they do not. A question about version X with an answer to that question is still a question about version X 10 years later. So the answer is still relevant. The question, maybe not so much.

Comment: Related: [Reputation Expiration and Deterioration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327557/289905).

Comment: @Gimby questions are RARELY version, so I don't know why everyone keeps bring this argument of "its still valid for that users scenario". The MAJORITY of question are generic enough to evolve over time. I.e "Whats the best way to string a string to a buffer in LANGUAGE"

Comment: Also you point doesn't change anything... It can remain the accepted answer but it's no longer useful to prioritise this answer over a newer up to date solution. You should think about this...

Comment: If you're arguing that the question should become obsolete, as opposed to accepted answer, then you'd be promoting the duplication of questions...

Comment: @Modus You probably can’t find it because [the question you’re thinking of was asked on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327557/reputation-expiration-and-deterioration).

Comment: It's very strange to see so many downvotes to a sensible feature request. I do not agree with the asker at all, because some old questions/answers are still useful and correct, but downvoting it this many times... Come on.

Comment: @LajosArpad https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384958/suggested-solutions?noredirect=1#comment696278_384958

Comment: @Tobiq unfortunately I do not have time now to read that, but I am shocked to see that a peaceful sensible question receives so much negative feedback. I do not agree with you at all, but would not downvote your question just for not agreeing with you.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of a question holds no responsibility to maintain the answer over time. This is totally ok, as sometimes dated answers are helpful (especially to people using legacy systems). Now, despite there being a check mark on the answer, (I personally wouldn't downvote the answer because it was correct at that time) what you could do is post a new answer with modern solutions, explaining why it works for this period of time.

I personally have... what 500+ answers? If it's my responsibility to maintain all of those answers, I'd quit the site -- it's just too much to do!

Information does not become obsolete, it becomes archived :)

Comment: I wasn't in favour of the answerer having to maintain their post. The problem is, the new answers won't get seen, because the 10 year old answer is hogging space. The accepted answer can remain as thats what the user accepted at the time, but for future reference it's not helpful seeing these dated answers. And it will also alleviate the need for the original poster to continuously edit the question over the years. Someone else can just come and post the answer (as opposed to leaving a comment and hoping the answer poster updates their answer), and naturally it will flow upwards.

Comment: Wouldn't the proposal benefit more then from altering the sort order of the answers? Ordering them by active would probably satisfy many of these cases. Also not everyone sorts by 'votes' as is.

Comment: @rlemon This whole question is about the revision of the sort order of answers. What do you mean by `ordering them by active`?

Comment: you already have the option to choose how the answers are ordered _for you_. this question doesn't read like you just want to change which is selected for the user. "If SO were to degrade votes over time, and also not place the accepted answer as the first result, users would benefit from getting the best current solution" you can already satisfy this for most cases by just selecting the 'active' tab on the top right of the question list. Working in voting + activity might be an interesting proposal, but do you think it would impact this situation much? I personally do not.

Comment: with that said, it might be worth considering ignoring the users sort selection on older questions and defaulting them to 'active' answers.. that proposal I see carrying more weight.