# Answers ordering when score are equal

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

There are currently 3 options for the answer ordering: "Active", "Oldest" and "Votes" (where "by score" is the default). The one exception is Accepted answer - which is pin to be first (if this right or not was discussed here: [please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top)).

When ordering by "vote", and having several answers with the same score - their internal order is random.

I may be wrong, but I have the feeling that when I see 2 answers with the same score - **the better one will be the one with the more comments** - don't have statistic data just a hunch.

I can see this most of the time where the score of the answer is 0-2. So no enough user voted to get the difference between fine, good or great answer.

As I cannot measure this I want to ask here: Do you also get this feeling?

If so, can we order answers with an equal score by the number of comments? (I know this can be abused to change the post place but still).

I am not saying it will always be a better order - just saying it will better than random

Comment: _the better one will be the one with the more comments_ what happens when comments on the post are deleted... How would one verify this?

Comment: What if the comments are saying that the answer did not work for them or that it has other problems?

Comment: I didn't say it correct all the time - I just think most if the time its true. And yes - there are cases in which it will order wrong - but I think it is better than random

Comment: Most of the time, post with lot of comment also have edit which improve them (after the comment read by the OP)

Comment: If one of the answers is really better, it should get more upvotes in the long run. What benefit do you see in ordering answers with equal score?

Comment: I know people can read all the answer but most of them read just the first 2/3. In the long run you correct - but having the answer with more chance to be better high will cause them to get upvote faster

Comment: If just leaving a bunch of comments would increase an answer's visibility, this would be an easy way to rig the system in your favour. Random is simple and fair, I don't see a reason to futz with it.

Answer (score 9):

The random order is deliberate to prevent bias.

> the better one will be the one with the more comments

Lengthy comments usually means the post is problematic/incomplete, because in ideal situation, a post *shouldn't* have any comment at all.

> Most of the time, post with lot of comment also have edit which improve them (after the comment read by the OP)

And that's when the comments should be flagged and deleted as "No Longer Needed". Unless your proposal is to always count for the total (including deleted) comments, but that may confuse readers even more because only mods can see deleted comments.