# When the answer with the most upvotes is not the accepted answer tell us at the outset and make it easy to get to each!

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

Often for many reasons the answer accepted by the OP is not the answer with the most upvotes. For many reasons it still might be the best answer, but it often isn't.

Currently the accepted answer is always listed first and there is no indication that there's one or many answers with more, often orders of magnitude more upvotes.

Sure if the question is short and the accepted answer is short you'll see at a glance.

But if the question is long, the accepted answer is long, the pair combined are long, or your screen is small; you won't know this until you invest time reading and scrolling.

Why not announce this at the outset?

---

### Note: nn answers are more popular than the accepted answer

---

### Jump to: [✔ accepted answer] [**↑** popular answers]

---

(It might also be worth a third icon & link for [newest answer]. Maybe also one for answer by highest-rep user, at least for users past some kind of threshold, overall or relating to the tags)

You could make these big when the page first loads, when you're scrolled to the top. And when you scroll down they can become compact but stay at the top so you can click back to re-read either the accepted or top answer to compare against some point you just read in one of the other answers.

In fact why not have a system-wide concept of "top answer"? You could build more features and achievments and hats and whatnot off it? Bronze/Silver/God for when your top answer is one/two/three orders of magnitude more popular than the accepted or second-most-popular answer.

Okay that's off topic, just gimme the links for now (-:

Comment: Maybe not an outright dupe, but certainly related... FYI: [Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top).

Comment: @yivi: I did look for similar suggestions. I've been thinking about this for years so couldn't believe it hadn't come up before... yet couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah, it's not always easy to find these things. I only got it quickly because I remembered the exact keywords.

Comment: Meta is somewhat wrong place to collect votes for this particular suggestion - almost everyone here knows that "accepted" check mark worth nothing... so not much value for users here. (I know that we don't have other place to vote for features...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: For me and other slow readers, bad through lengthy but wrong/outdated accepted answers and their comments can be a big timewaster. I can only imagine how it must be for someone using a screenreader.

Comment: [This answer from years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161980/154292) covers part of my suggestion.

Comment: I did try to solve this with my userscript that does a [Table of contents in the sidebar](https://stackapps.com/questions/7994/sticky-post-headers-question-table-of-contents), which gives you an overview of the scores of each post, which one is accepted, and clicking on the links will scroll to the answers. Especially useful (!) when there are more than one page of answers!

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Very nice! Please feel free to add any of the features I mentioned to it.