# Notifications when an answer other than the one accepted got more votes

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications

#### For the person who asks the question

I understand it can be complicated when a question is very active since this can change often, but in terms of the UX that should not be a problem (e.g. it could be based on a threshold, or difference, or simply wait for some time window, if truly needed, before notifying you).

At a minimum I think the person who asks the question may want to know that another answer is really the one people are finding most useful over time. It can also help others who quickly read the accepted answer but may not realize that there is another answer with possibly many more votes / updated information.

#### For readers

SO could also FYI readers **in the accepted answer itself** e.g. with a flag or icon, that the accepted answer is **not** the most voted one. Moreover, that icon could even have a link that scrolls to that most voted answer.

Comment: Interesting idea, and probably helpful. I have no idea how difficult this would be to implement, though - or what any possible side-effects (there are *always* side-effects) would be.

Comment: I mainly support the last paragraph of your question, also because quite often, if a more recent better answer comes in, the OP just isn't around anymore to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @ErikA i updated the OP to clarify that distinction.

Answer (score -3):

### Notifications:

If you are the question asker, you are already notified when each answer is posted.

You have your chance to change your acceptance, if you gave it previously to another answer, then.

Why would you change your mind because an answer that you've already seen is gathering upvotes? It doesn't make a lot of sense, IMO. And if not for changing the acceptance, why would you need to be notified of how the different answers are being voted upon?

This idea seems simply like a way to nudge the question asker into changing their acceptance mark. I don't think that's necessary nor appropriate.

### Interface

We already have UI elements for readers to discover this: the green check-mark, and the score number. Adding yet another UI element would not make things more discoverable for readers.

---

All in all, I personally don't see the use for this. Most of this would be better solved by simply [unpin the accepted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top), which would be immediately more useful without having to notify anyone.

Comment: The second answer may get edited / enriched over time. Separately, the question asker may not realize at the point in time they read the just posted answer that it's really a better solution. Speaking from personal experience.

Comment: I still believe it is a complicated solution for a simple problem: accepted answers should not be pinned to the top.

Comment: Sure, but even in that case, the idea would still apply, in reverse - Readers may want to 1) know that the accepted answer is a different one from the one with most votes, and 2) get a quick link to easily scroll to it (in a sense, that's what a pin does, it makes it easy / predictable to find the accepted answer).

Comment: There are already UI elements for readers: the green check-mark, and the score number. Adding yet another UI element would not make things more discoverable for readers.

Comment: I don't think there is a UI element that does what I mentioned (tell you specifically that there is an answer with *more* votes in the context of the top answer everyone sees first). Also, how do you know _"it would not make things more discoverable"_? Have you or the site actually tried that?

Comment: I don't need to try it out to have an opinion. The same way you haven't tried it out yet, yet have the opinion that something like this should be implemented.