# Requesting again to unpin the accepted answer from the top

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

In 2016 I wrote the post [Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top). Although there was a lot of community support for it at the time, the request was declined because of a lack of consensus among the SE team. Since there have been some changes in the leadership over the last year or two as well as a stated desire to listen more to the community, I am making another request to re-evaluate the decision.

I won't repeat all of the arguments I made last time, but this is a request to allow the highest voted answer to rise to the top instead of being stuck under a lower voted accepted answer. This is already the behavior for accepted self-answers.

Note that this is *not* a request to change the accepted answer or remove the green accepted check mark. It is only a request allow the accepted answer to be sorted by the same rules that all the other answers get sorted by.

I'm a little biased in my request because my answering strategy is often to write (what I believe to be) quality answers to old questions. Although I don't know how to count them, I have many, many answers that are stuck below the accepted answer. In my experience the original poster has rarely ever changed the accepted answer. Indeed, I myself rarely have the energy to analyze a new answer I get on a question I asked years ago. I believe letting the community move the useful answers all the way to the top would improve the current situation.

Thank you for your reconsideration.

Comment: What makes you think that previously **declined** feature-request would get different treatment now? In particular I don't think there was a single feature request this year that was implemented... so I don't see value in bringing this one up now. (also I totally support the request)

Comment: comment on the original answer and refer to your answer, which may or may not be better, like we all do

Comment: In my opinion, the accepted answer should have something special about it (and the checkmark alone is not enough). That being said, I _do_ think that changes need to be made but I prefer something like this proposal: [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666/348196)

Comment: _"Although I don't know how to count them, I have many, many answers that are stuck below the accepted answer"_ That inspired me to create an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1313904). In case you're wondering, you have 86

Comment: This feature request has my vote, but it does not have my hope.

Comment: @41686d6564, Thank you for making that SEDE query. I've wanted to learn how to do that a few times but it always seemed to complicated.