# Why was this discussion closed as a duplicate of another unrelated one?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, reopen-closed, dupehammer

A user recently asked [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408015/answers-votes-if-answers-have-same-vote-count-accepted-should-be-higher-ranked), which was asking about the order of answers displayed in one's activity tab in their profile. [Screenshot because it's deleted (credit to dbc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MG9R.png). The question itself was worded perfectly. It had good grammar, and was asked in a constructive manner.

The premise of the question was something like this:

> In the answers tab in my activity, if I sort all of my answers by votes, answers with the same score are sorted. But if one answer is accepted, and the other is not, they are sorted randomly.
>
> [image]
>
> Shouldn't the accepted answer be on top? Or is this such a small thing that there is no point in fixing it?

This feature-request was received negatively, which is fine. Personally, I disagree with the premise of the question and I *did* downvote it. That's not the point of this question, though.

Later, a user with  a gold badge in the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag closed it as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top), and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402290/requesting-again-to-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top). These two questions ask for the accepted answer to be unpinned on an actual question. [Like in this case, the accepted answer shouldn't be pinned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANe7X.png). That's what the
two questions ask for.

To me, the two questions do not seem to be duplicates. They are barely related, and it shouldn't have been closed. Closing a feature-request as a duplicate of another feature-request which isn't related is wrong. It shuts down the discussion, and is sending the message that an unpopular feature request should just be closed and shut down, without any discussion whatsoever.

After the duplicate closure, the user deleted their question, likely because the question was dismissed in this way. So one can say that the closure was just a way of shutting down the discussion.

Is it OK to just close down a discussion which was previously never brought up? Isn't that wrong? Can the gold badger please tell us why they thought the two questions were duplicates?

Comment: Meta is not responsible for self-deletes. The dupe hammering was wrong. Makoto has to explain themselves which I assume will happen shortly.

Comment: @rene Meta *can* be, however, responsible for undeleting and reopening the question...

Comment: @rene I never blamed meta for anything. I just linked the related discussion, because this event strongly reminded me of the other one.

Comment: @TylerH I would be happy to post on Meta *Can we slow down on the undeletes on Meta, folks?* so don't try me.

Comment: What's wrong with undeleting the feature-request?

Comment: @10Rep you certainly did blame meta by bringing up a post you feel strong about but has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: The discussion was _never_ "shut down". Closed as dupe, OP deleted rather than explaining why it's not, I fail to see the problem

Comment: @Nick The problem is that it shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate of an obviously unrelated question, by a user with a badge in every tag here on meta.

Comment: @10Rep forcing one to defend the FR their decided not to care about is ... somewhat not nice. You can always post improved version of FR yourself and defend it as author.

Comment: @10Rep The problem is we get asked the same dupes time and time again (which results in the occasional bad closure) and people would rather back out than try to defend themselves, again, that's OPs problem.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not sure I want to take responsibility for undeleting a post that was not well received yet where the author decided to not challenge the closure and not make a case for its value.

Comment: It was an incorrect dupe closure IMO. but i don't think we lost anything of value. go next

Comment: @KevinB ??? The question was a feature-request. Half the question here on meta don't have value by that argument. Let's dupe-hammer them all now.

Comment: @10Rep not all feature requests are equal.

Comment: The original FR is unclear. I had to switch on a few more braincells to grasp what their image and request was about (I saw it before it was closed/deleted FTR). In that sense you do a better job here explaining what the FR is about.

Comment: I'm not suggesting this post should have been deleted. I'm suggesting it's deleted now and there's no real reason to undo it. If the op wants to undelete it and improve it, they can

Comment: I feel that even I'm going off track of what my question is asking. I disagree with the premise of the FR. I don't want to ask it again because I disagree with it. I am really just asking the dupe hammer about why they did the incorrect dupe closure.

Comment: I would assume it's just an honest mistake, as I too initially thought it was about answer sorting in a question's answer list

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this comment thread. I thought if someone feels a closure is wrong, they should challenge it. Not just leave it for the author to sort out.

Comment: @KevinB I can't relate with that, because the original question had an image which made it immediately clear what the question is about (at least to me). And anyway, shouldn't one understand the premise of a question clearly before closing it as a dupe?

Comment: @10Rep the image is what changed my mind. people make mistakes, that's life. fortunately there's a path forward to correct it if the OP chooses to take it.

Comment: @KevinB I get that it's a mistake, but I thought if I disagreed with a closure I could raise it on meta. I hope that this won't hold the gold badger on the spot (that's not my intent), I just hope tht this question will prevent mistakes like this in the future.

Comment: I just don't feel like it's right forcing the OP back into the spotlight if they chose to delete it and move on.

Comment: @Scratte yes, if that was the only event involved. Now we have wrong closure and a self delete. We can still discuss the wrong closure but it is a bit of a challenge if we want to repair that on a now deleted question. But technically you're absolutely right and we could also move on to just discussing the wrong dupe hammer first / foremost.

Comment: @rene I almost agree with you. I considered what I might have done if I had been in that same situation. Picking a fight to get it re-opened (if I disagreed with the closure), or just delete it. I'm pretty sure I'd have chosen the second option. Picking a fight with a dupe-hammer just seems so.. insurmountable.

Comment: @Scratte You should try picking a fight with Makoto. Worth it.

Comment: @rene I just want a change... hopefully Makoto will go easy on me ;)

Comment: "The question itself was worded perfectly. It had good grammar" I don't know why this is relevant to whenever or not we close the question. My questions usually have poor grammar and abysmal wording, yet they aren't closed.

Comment: I think I understand Makoto's reasoning (feel free to prove me wrong) here. The idea behind the request in question is the same as in the reasoning behind pinning the accepted answer on top - that is, the (highly flawed IMO) premise that the accepted is somehow "better" than the unaccepted. This means that the linked targets are not unrelated. I am not sure whether the closure was warranted, though, because one has to make an inference to connect those 2 (probably should've been provided as a  "tangentially related" comment).

Comment: @OlegValter Well, you were wrong :-P

Comment: @41686d654 - I guess so :)

Comment: @Scratte: Hopefully this shows a bit of my human side.  If I believe I'm in the right I'll stand my ground; If I'm in demonstrably in the wrong I'm happy to admit that and correct it.

Comment: Hmm, what's with the 2 close votes? I don't see what details this question needs....

Comment: @10Rep We can create a new meta post about the closure of this post, in case it gets a third close vote :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I might have read this one a bit *too* fast. Here's what I was keying off of.

> Why not all? Well you see, accepted answers with say (3) votes can be ranked lower than a non-accepted answer with (3) votes.

I believe I was in the mentality of this being a request to reorder answers *in a question*, not answers *in a user's profile*.  On premise, the original question doesn't make a whole lot of sense since the order of answers isn't based on acceptance criteria, it's based on either its votes, its activity, or its age.

(That probably would've been a reasonable answer.)

My apologies!  Looks like it's been reopened.  I'll be a bit more careful going forward.

Comment: No problem, I'm sure the OP may have deleted their feature request anyways (as it was getting received negatively). I just wanted to know the reason behind the closure :)