# If answers have the same vote-count, accepted should appear higher in user-profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, sorting

When I go to check my answers (ranked from highest vote-count to lowest), mostly everything is in order.

Why not all? Well you see, accepted answers with say (3) votes can be ranked lower than a non-accepted answer with (3) votes:

[image: Order of answers when accepted with same number of votes]

This does not look clean when browsing through my answers. Instead, I suggest ranking the same vote-count answers with accepted first to not accepted. Is this one of those things where it's such a small detail there is no point changing it?

Comment: When you are sorting by votes, what "not vote related" criteria should impact the sorting when the votes are equal? i would expect activity, or views, to be more important than accepted status.

Comment: The closure of this post is being discussed in [Why was this discussion closed as a duplicate of another unrelated one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408017/why-was-this-discussion-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-another-unrelated-one) cc @Makoto

Comment: I believe the answers *are* sorted consistently. The second sort criteria for them appears to be *date*.

Comment: @jpmc26 That [doesn't seem to be the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUfl3.png)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo It possibly counts edits, too. Your answer from 2020.01.20 was edited on 2020.11.25, your answer from 2019.08.05 was edited on 2020.11.29 and that's why it may have ended up higher in the list.

Comment: @JeanneDark Good catch! It's probably that...

Comment: How come this question was undeleted and reopened?

Comment: It was the topic of another meta question disputing the closure and some people decided to undelete off the back of that. Then others agreed with the premise of the other question and reversed the closure

Comment: @BuddyBob The question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. Unfortunately, we couldn't reopen it in time before you deleted it. Thus, I and others cast undelete votes so that we could then reopen it.

Comment: @Scratte: I've responded.  Sorry about the mess!

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, answers are sorted by score and then by last edit time, which is unfortunately not clearly shown.

I think it makes sense to take into account the answer time, as a more recent answer with the same score is probably better than an older one, since it was able to attract votes faster.

On the other hand, [an accepted answer merely indicates that it was helpful for the question author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268959/what-does-accepting-an-answer-actually-convey-2015-edition/268980#268980). It is not a guarantee of quality – the question author's view should not have more weight in it, [as requested in the past for sorting answers on questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/525036).

We could argue that the second sorting criteria should be the initial answer date (which is displayed) instead of the last edit date, but it does not look like a big issue.

Comment: " since it was able to attract votes faster." didn't think about that.

Comment: @BuddyBob that is, if you consider it makes sense to compare the score of answers on different questions 