# When tied for votes, show accepted answer at top

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

Accepted answers are [no longer at the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410859/316760), but should be when tied. At time of writing, that doesn't seem to be the case ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433342/net-sdk-project-nuget-packaging-add-tools-folder)). Please favor accepted answer in a tie.

[image: screen shot of example situation]

Comment: This feature is already supported and was implemented in [November 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369569/1099857). An accepted answer will appear above an unaccepted answer with the same score (excluding accepted self-answers) as long as the sort method is "Highest score (default)" as noted in [the answer below](/a/418656).

Comment: As Henry notes, the "feature" you propose has already been implemented and is how the system currently works. If you reference the screenshot you included, you'll see (in the top right-hand corner) that you have the sort order for answers set to "Date modified (newest first)". So, that's how the answers are being sorted. You aren't sorting by score, so there is no "tie".

Comment: I'm sorry about how things are going in your personal life. Do know that your contributions to this site are valued; the reputation and accepts you've earned speaks to that. I feel compelled to point out that downvotes are not to be taken personally (they apply only to the *post*, not the user), and nobody downvotes in order to feel superior. Especially on Meta sites, votes are a noise-free way of rating the relevance and interestingness of the questions. Feature requests, like this one, are downvoted simply because people disagree with them. It's not "toxic" to disagree with something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you sort the answers. Sorting by "Highest score" will result in the accepted answer being displayed first. Because you have sorted by "Date modified (newest first)", the newest answer shows up first.

Comment: If you'd like to experiment a bit, [here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106282/is-there-a-way-i-can-print-multiple-lines-using-one-print?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) with two answers tied (note: votes are subject to change).

Comment: You're right. Interesting, though, I didn't know there was a sort order so I have no idea how mine got changed from default. ‍♀️